# Why is there no swag contest in this year's SO Survey?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2017

I just took the survey and was looking forward to the end expecting there was something to win again (I estimated the coins in the piggy bank correctly last year).

Now I'm a bit disappointed: all I get is a **lousy BADGE**? No swag anymore? Where has the swag gone?

Comment: How about a pin saying "I took the 2017 Stack Overflow survey and all I got was this lousy badge"?

Comment: @deceze better than nothing!

Answer (score 10):

Come up with something interesting, and we might just run it.

Comment: take a picture of a big stackoverflow logo/banner in your office, and we have to guess how many pixels were in the original image that it was generated from.

Comment: How about giving a free t-shirt to the users who write the top, say, 5 answers to the [topic suggestions question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357936/developer-survey-2018-any-topic-suggestions)? \*smiles innocently\*

Comment: @Tanner None in this one: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=2bb144720a66