# Developer Survey 2018: Any Topic Suggestions?

Tags: discussion, survey-2018

We're getting close to the end of the year, which means another annual [Developer Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017)! As we've done in [previous years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319221/what-else-should-we-ask-developers), we'd like to ask for your thoughts and suggestions when it comes to the most important things that we should be asking developers.

We've got the usual staples covered such as [demographic info](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#developer-profile) and the most [dreaded, wanted and loved technologies](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#technology); what else do you think we should cover?

We don't need folks to come up with the survey questions themselves; we're most interested in any premise you'd like to share, so that we can better shape the questions as we put it together. Things like:

- Did we touch on something last year that you'd like to see us explore more comprehensively this year? What is it, and how could we dig deeper?
- Was there something in the news this year that you found interesting that you'd like to see us ask folks about?
- Do you have an idea for something fun we could include to help keep the tone of the survey bright?

Again, [here is a link to the 2017 survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017) for reference if you need it. Remember, we're looking for ideas at this point; please don't feel as if you need to spend a lot of time writing the perfect question for us to include.

Our survey is already comprehensive (also known as 'really freaking long'), so we can't promise to include every question or idea, but your input will help us investigate the things that matter the most.

A big thanks in advance to all that take a moment to share an idea!

**Update**

Thank you, everyone, who took a little time to offer a suggestion! All of these were helpful, many *should* be included but for the sake of what little brevity we have left in the survey, only a few of them can be.

Everyone is welcome to continue to leave suggestions, but we're in the process now of turning ideas into questions that fit in the survey and we're pretty much full at this point.

Thank you again to everyone that spent a little time to lend their ideas, we really appreciate it!

Comment: Please don't assume everybody taking the survey is a professional programmer. Last year there were a lot of questions that assumed I'm a professional programmer, but I'm not (for example I remember there was one like "how long have you coded for work?"). I suggest having a question asking "are you a professional programmer?", and users who answer "no" to that question won't get any questions that only professional programmers can answer.

Comment: Alcohol habits of successful programmers. Def.

Comment: It would be nice to see the questions, possible answers, and the answers I gave after the fact.  Right now I'm not sure these are available except while taking the survey.

Comment: @DonaldDuck and not just streamlining the survey to hide questions irrelevant based on previous answers, but also allowing additional useful questions that wouldn't apply to everyone

Comment: Have you guys [found "something interesting" this year?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341946/4099593). ;)

Comment: Minimum amount of screens needed to do job well. Partly serious

Comment: Related to what @DonaldDuck said: Don't assume that everyone works in a large corporation. In the previous years there have been some questions that didn't even contain suitable options for freelancers or the self-employed (e.g. "how many people work in your company" options starting from 2.)

Comment: If y'all do the "how frequently do you check in code" question again, I'd like to see another option for "definitely when the laptop starts making a weird noise."

Comment: @DonaldDuck I like your suggestion. Just wanted to add that if for whatever reason we cannot change the format of the survey (for example no conditional questions allowed), we could have "Following section is targeted to professional programmers. Please proceed to question N if this doesn't apply to you"

Comment: @user5226582 Or else add an option "I'm not a professional programmer" to those questions. For example, for "how long time have you coded professionally", the possible answers would be "X years", "Y years", "Z years" and "I don't code professionally". As another example, for the question "Does your company encourage you to stay up to date with technology you're working with?" suggested below, the possible answers would be "Yes", "No" and "I don't work for any programming company".

Comment: @DonaldDuck yeah, that could be the default selected value (to save time).

Comment: I never seem to know what to use for my role type, in both the annual survey, as well as the recent Stack Overflow salary calculator tool. There are many developers that would consider their domain best described by [computational science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_science) or "scientific computing". Since this tends to result in desktop (or HPC) computer applications, I tend to select "Desktop Developer". Although if there is a distinction to be made for "Data Scientist" (which I also don't think is a great fit for us) I think the aforementioned new category would be useful.

Comment: I'd like to see some questions about cost of living as related to salary. So people can more easily judge if there salary is competitive for the area they live/work in.

Comment: I would like to see the number of questions reduced to something more reasonable.   I agree you got some awesome stats out of last years survey but seriously it was way to long.  If it takes more then 5 minutes most people wont complete it.  I think i got some achievement for completing it last year.

Comment: The 2017 survey results show a rather short list (10) of "frameworks, libraries, and other technologies". Did the actual question only include these as options? (I'm too lazy to look at the raw result set) Can it be open-ended this year if it wasn't last time?

Comment: I work part-time. I am always not sure what to select as salary. Should I select what I would earn if I worked full-time? Would be good to make that clear in the next survey.

Comment: There should be special questions for woman developers. Since the social political climate is pushing to have more woman in coding. As a woman developer, it would be nice to have a voice in what works and what does not.

Comment: Could I know when the survey results will be published ? We are in 1-2018!

Comment: Just came here looking for any traces of other people wondering about the SO 2018 marketing analysis campaign. Seriously, I had to abandon that thing after the sixth consecutive question about my ad-blocking behavior (and related). WTF? SO has the right to do marketing research, but shouldn't label it "Developer survey".

Comment: The question is not a problem description, thus the criteria of "reproducibility" is not defined on it. Leave open.

Comment: I think the survey should also focus more on developing countries in Africa when conducting surveys so that we could have a greater understanding of how things work in this part of the world

Answer (score 247):

> What time do you usually wake up in workdays?

I wanted to confirm my theory that most programmers are <strike>batman</strike> human bats.

Comment: That's interesting - it could somehow tell us the importance of flexible work hours :)

Comment: We would know who to blame for the long Travis builds.

Comment: Should this question distinguish between people who officially work the graveyard shift vs the typical sunshine dwellers?

Comment: I'd love to work graveyard shifts, alas, i can not

Comment: I thnk wake up but also get into work and leave? I'm up early most days but at work quite late

Comment: Waking up normally occurs circa 10 min after first coffee consumption, no?

Comment: This question should be related with "what time do office workers in your area usually wake up". E.G: Spain and U.K. are in the same meridian but do not share time zone. This implies that normal office starting hours might be 8:00 in Spain and 9:00 in U.K. (I don't know what are the actual hours).

Comment: I was pretty sure I remember this being a question in a previous survey; something like, "If you could start working at any time, when would be your ideal hours?" Results were quite disappointing to me. My bat-like hours did not appear to be normal.

Comment: I'd LIKE to be a bat, but I have kids that need to be gotten onto the school bus.

Comment: I'd be interested to see "when you'd _like_ to wake up" vs. "when you _have_ to wake up."

Comment: Also add when do you go to sleep.

Comment: Also add "how many hours of sleep you get every night". [Research shows](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/sleep-deprivation-epidemic-health-effects-tired-heart-disease-stroke-dementia-cancer-a7964156.html) just how important sleep is. Also in Japan [death from overworking is common](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/world/woman-japan-dies-overwork-common-death-article-1.3542948).

Comment: I have flexible work time, but I was asked nicely to try to not arrive after 9:30. So I basically always arrive at the same time, not flexible at all. I would wake up ~3-4 hours later than I currently do, if it was allowed. So yes, a difference between "when do you wake up" and "when would you like to wake up" would have been nice.

Answer (score 178):

How about some health-related questions:

- On average, how much time do you spend on a computer/phone/tablet every day?
- On average, how much time do you spend outside every day?
- How often do you skip lunch so you can get more work done?
- Do you have a standing desk?
- [From](/questions/357936/developer-survey-2018-any-topic-suggestions/357981#comment523614_357981) [making3](/users/724591/making3): How often do you exercise per week?

These may need to be adjusted if people find them a little too personal or guilt-inducing. (Or maybe that just means they're good questions...)

Comment: Since I don't wanna steal the health-related idea, I'd like to know "How often do you exercise per week?".

Comment: @making3 "_probably not enough_" should be an option :)

Comment: I'd add height and weight questions to calculate BMIs.

Comment: I'm all for this, but on the other hand there are a metric ton of health questions related to developers or the workforce in general, you can create a survey on it's own for it. Let's avoid questions related to lunch for example, I think I can come up with close to a hundred questions :)

Comment: coffee consumption?

Comment: *Health? What Framework is this about?*

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Health is an advanced, platform-agnostic framework that enables developers to write good code more efficiently. As far as I know, it's been ported into every language. It's so popular that Amazon [bought one of the major distros](http://money.cnn.com/2017/06/16/investing/amazon-buying-whole-foods/index.html). Many people prefer the open-source versions.

Comment: It would be interesting to include questions about symptoms e.g. back pain, OOS/RSI, diabetes, eyesight etc. Especially if the survey runs for many years, and you look at habits now causing problems later. But of course there are issues around asking such sensitive questions.

Comment: Is amount of sleep already in previous surveys? I can't remember.

Comment: i especially like the standing desk thing, although the question should be "how many hours do you work standing up" since there are many solutions to do that

Comment: @Orangesandlemons about coffee i posted https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358021/436085

Comment: Also add "how many hours of sleep you get every night". [Research shows](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/sleep-deprivation-epidemic-health-effects-tired-heart-disease-stroke-dementia-cancer-a7964156.html) just how important sleep is. Also in Japan [death from overworking is common](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/world/woman-japan-dies-overwork-common-death-article-1.3542948).

Comment: And all of the sudden, insurance premiums for software developers sees a sharp increases...

Comment: How many steps do you walk in a week? Possible with options to choose.

Comment: Beverage consumption percentage is definitely one to add: coffee, tea, soda, energy drinks, water. I find programmers pretty biased on their beverages for some reason.

Comment: I don't specifically exercise, I just move around quite a bit all the time, because that's just how I am. So I had to check "0", even though I have enough activity. Ok, maybe I could have counted "running to trains" as exercise.

Answer (score 167):

> Do you participate in open source outside of work?

It would be interesting to see what fraction of people who have a Real Job at a company still manage to carve out time for OSS.

> Does your company support open source?
>
> - No
> - We donate money to projects that we use
> - We allow people to work on open source as part of work
> - We have some employees work on open source full time

​

> What hosting service do you use for your (company|open source) code?
>
> - GitHub.com
> - GitHub Enterprise
> - BitBucket (Bitbucket Cloud)
> - Stash (Bitbucket Server)
> - Sourceforge
> - GitLab
> - Team Foundation Server <sup>(Thanks [Cerbrus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus))</sup>
> - Visual Studio Online <sup>(Thanks [AndyJ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/310988/andyj)!)</sup>
> - Gitea <sup>(Thanks [Jonas Franz](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2792899/jonas-franz)!)</sup>
> - Other, please specify
>     _________________

(Feel free to edit and add more sites)

Comment: "Participate" is very vague. It could mean anything from filing a bug report to being the principal maintainer of a project.

Comment: @200_success The question could be presented as a gradation -- **How do you participate in open source? (Click all that apply)**, with options like "_testing_", "_filed issues_", "_principal maintainer of a project's code_", "_initiator of accepted pull request_", "_principal maintainer of a project's documentation_", "_contributor of minor fixes to a project's documentation_" etc. Also, some of these items might be split into their own questions, each with it's own gradation (e.g. contribute to code vs contribute to documentation vs testing).

Comment: In addition I would ask "How many commits you have done during the past month" and "How many different projects you made commits to"

Comment: This would be interesting on two counts. As stated, and also what proportion of companies that use open source don't actually support it.

Comment: GitLab online / GitLab selfhost?

Comment: I totally contribute to open source! I requested a typo correction in readme.txt!

Answer (score 131):

I'm interested to see how the day-to-day challenges other developers have compare to mine, so I'd like to ask:

> What is your greatest obstacle to productivity as a developer?

some options to start with:

- Distracting work environment
- Being tasked with non-development work
- Lack of support from management
- Meetings
- [image: This]
- My other job/schoolwork
- Inadequate access to necessary tools

There are other, probably better options to choose from, so please feel free to edit and add/modify. It could maybe be a multiple pick/ranking kind of thing.

Maybe it could also include an "other" free-response box where people could write in things like "My Stack Overflow questions keep getting closed", "I don't know how to exit vim", "mom keeps telling me to go outside", etc.

Comment: _"My Stack Overflow questions keep getting closed"_  :D  that looks good

Comment: Upvoted for "I don't know how to exit vim", although it's Emacs for me! I'd also like to see this question in conjunction with "Do you work in open-plan, cubicles, shared office, private office, treehouse?"

Comment: Stack Overflow is. Once you pop, you can't stop.

Comment: add option : waiting on blockers

Comment: Nominated myself as a moderator on Flag Overflow.

Comment: It is definitely when SO crashes.

Comment: +: Lack of an acceptable Software Engineering process; Bad management decision making;

Comment: @falsarella oh yeah, those guys look familiar too.

Comment: Hot Network Qs have got to be responsible for a number of lost hours, unless its just me...

Comment: Alcohol abuse ? Lack of sleep ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier those are definitely obstacles to productivity as a developer, but not _specifically_, more as a subset of obstacles to productivity as a human. But still valid. There are other things like that too. Maybe they could be grouped into a broad category of "personal issues".

Comment: the biggest obstacle I face everyday is interruptions: of any kind, mostly phone calls, im's, emails, etc.

Comment: @eddyce notifications from stack overflow when someone pings you in a comment...

Comment: @Don'tPanic still interruption:)

Comment: @mbrig I finally had to add a user stylesheet rule to hide them :)  It was mentally distracting just to see/read the links even if I never clicked through

Comment: Personally developing software in a 3rd world country my biggest challenges are lack of power and good internet connection this are challenges which i face as freelancer working in an office environment i would say the biggest productivity killer is unnecessary interruptions  from colleagues

Answer (score 98):

The 2017 survey asked for the company size. We should also ask for the team size. This would only include the developers.

> What is the size of your team ?
>
> - Alone
> - 2 - 5
> - 6 - 10
> - 11 - 15
> - 16+

Comment: Although we may have a common census, team may be a little vague... One may be part of: contract team, project team, module team, feature team, scrum team, front end team, back end team, ux team... Other may work in multiple teams, or have teams that are a superset of other teams, intersecting teams, etc...

Comment: @falsarella This could be another question linked to this one : `Are you working for one or multiple teams ?`. This question could be changed to an average size between the teams

Comment: I think this information would be even more useful if it is combined with company size and # of developers in company. So for example, an answer can be 200 total employees, 50 developers, 5 team members.

Comment: Why only developers though? Dev/ops is the buzzword of the decade.

Comment: Aside from developers, we consider our designer and product owner part of our team (and just so happens to be enough to jump the border from 2-5 to 6-10).  If it truly means only developers, that should be part of the question.

Answer (score 89):

I'm curious about lunch:

> 1. Where do you get your food, at work?
>
>    - I bring my own food.
>    - I can buy food at work.
>    - Food is provided at work.
>    - I eat outside of the office or at home.
>    - I don’t eat during work hours.
> 2. Do you eat with your colleagues?

Comment: Maybe we would need an option for people eating elsewhere, but i'm not sure how to word it... Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: "eat outside of the office or at home" is probably something that everyone understands the same, and gives an option for people who work from home too. Also *"I can but food at work"* - probably "I can buy food at work" :) The "provided" option is then specifically provided for free.

Comment: Thanks, @Gimby. I've updated the suggestion.

Comment: What if a developer works from home and eats at home? Does that count as eating at office or as eating at home?

Comment: Maybe this question could be hidden if the user filled in he's working from their home, earlier in the questionnaire...

Comment: Oh no, are we doing that hidden questions thing again? "Survey complete; only 57% left to go!"

Comment: @CodyGray: Sounds like there's plenty of experience with it now ;-)

Comment: I'd add "Do you have lunch at your office desk?"

Comment: We should probably make this multiple choice for the people who work at companies that order lunch half the time.

Comment: @yacc follow up question for that: "how gross is your keyboard?"

Comment: @CodyGray Sounds like a question for [Caroline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341410/who-the-heck-is-caroline) to me

Comment: Missing option: Don't eat lunch/don't eat during work hours.

Comment: Added, @NemanjaTrifunovic

Answer (score 75):

> Does your company encourage you to stay up to date with technology you're working with?

#### Details

There are many programming languages and frameworks are used nowadays. The developers behind it keeps updating it and releasing new versions. So, if you are working in a company which uses a technology that changes frequently, means if suppose the company you're working for uses Angular 2, then Angular 4 is released later. Did your company encourage you to learn the changes and migrate to Angular 4 or do they want you to stay in the same version because it costs more time and money for them?

Comment: It would be important to distinguish between encourage on your own time vs. encourage on company time.

Comment: yes. Some companies spend working hours to do this. some companies provide resources but the person have to find time for this and some companies won't provide anything at all

Comment: "...and if not, do you do so on your own?"

Comment: I'd like to 2-part this and additionally ask people if they think they are using legacy, outdated, up-to-date, new or bleeding edge tech stacks.

Comment: @Ross you can add that as answer. that's a good question to ask people whether they are aware of the latest technology and it's benefits and/ or still working with old tech without updating them self.

Comment: Seems to me to only be able to represent the distribution of people’s subjective views regarding whether they feel that their unidentified tech is super new or super old. That is heir perspective and you can’t even measure whether Mary and John are agreeing or disagreeing that X is old or new.

Comment: I would be interested in knowing what's _"people’s subjective views regarding [...] their unidentified tech..."._

Comment: I'd be curious about hardware too - The specs of your development PC just to be able to compare what other companies are providing their developers.. It would be interesting to see how many of us suffer trying to code using under powered machines.

Comment: This could include options like paid education, tech conventions, company hackathons, etc

Answer (score 70):

> how often*, you had to do some non-programming work and what was it?
>
> - management
> - graphic design
> - user experience design
> - seo
> - data analysis / web analytics
> - system administration
> - hardware (includes lan, etc)
> - tech support (phone or email)
> - marketing
> - advertising
> - content upload/management
> - cyber security

(*)*in the scale of "never, sometimes, frequently, I hardly do the work I was hired for!"*

Comment: Add content upload/management -> do this when at my job when needed

Comment: "how good were you at it?" [Uh oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Comment: yeah, maybe that's too self ...something :)

Comment: The list is missing general IT work e.g. hardware repairs/replacements, technical support, unjamming the printer, etc. There will be a lot of people who are the sole IT person and programmer at a company. Or people will simply ask programmers to do it because IT and programming both involve computers so they must be the same thing.

Comment: @SGR I wanted to keep the list clear of things that everybody in IT does, I am tempted by tech support though

Comment: @eddyce Then perhaps a preceding question along the lines of "Where you hired solely as a programmer or as a member of IT with a programming role". Then lead into a question about how many IT related things you normally do if the person responds that they were solely hired as a programmer.

Comment: the truth is that nobody is hired solely as a programmer, maybe we should reconsider this whole thing?

Comment: "Have you ever harmed yourself by taking on one of these other responsibilities?" (I ruined my thumb having to crimp cat5 cable when we moved offices).

Comment: all good points, I just added hw, sysadm, tech support

Comment: + cyber and information security mayhaps.

Comment: Wait.  User Experience Design isn't part of building interfaces for your apps?

Comment: @SGR I'd ask the followup what else do you do question either way.  Possibly asking what other duties were given as part of your job when hired vs what you're actually doing.

Comment: @GuySchalnat building interfaces is when you already know where to put the buttons, the labels, what a swipe right will do, etc. UX design is deciding all this

Comment: @eddyce Oh.  I guess I'm a User Experience Designer as well.  I'm not sure how that is any different from gathering requirements?  Or Architect?  None of these involve writing code, but they all involve describing how the code is to be written.

Comment: @GuySchalnat I kind of agree with you but this job is getting more and more specialised every day. Where do we draw a line?, cause there must be one, for the sake of this poll at least.

Comment: @eddyce Maybe we should ask?

Comment: "How many times" - that's a bit specific. I suggest "how often", in the scale of "never, sometimes, frequently, I hardly do the work I was hired for!" :)

Comment: DevOps?  For those of us in a safety-critical and/or government industry, I would also include compliance/contractual/certification related activities.

Comment: @Darthfett  devops is still development though, i would not call it non-programming

Answer (score 69):

> Does your company follow a strict dress code?

**Why**

Most of the product based companies I know don’t enforce a dress code for it's employees.

In case of service based companies, some companies enforce a strict dress code but some don’t.

Comment: ... and, if they do: (1) do you approve of the code and (2) does it enhance or diminish your ability to work?

Comment: That would be interesting to see if devs in suits earn better...

Comment: Dress code = indention? Yeah I use indention! Any other questions you'd like to ask a programmer? :)

Comment: If it does - how strictly does it enforce?

Comment: Maybe `Which is the dress code in your company`?

Comment: Dress code might be entirely a social aspect.  No one shows up in their PJs because no one else does.

Comment: ... wait you mean that these actually exists, at all?

Answer (score 67):

I am going to repeat my suggestion from [the last time this was asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319221/what-else-should-we-ask-developers/319295#319295):

## **Impostor Syndrome**

I think it would be interesting to measure confidence in self vs confidence in others:

- On a scale of 1 to 10, how would you rate your programming ability?
- On a scale of 1 to 10, how would you rate the programming ability of your peers?
- On a scale of 1 to 10, how would your peers rate your programming ability?

This would not just measure the [Dunning-Kruger Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect); it would also measure [impostor syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome), which is an issue that affects women, minorities, and other under-represented groups in computer science. (**Note:** I know that impostor syndrome also affects the rest of us. But it's a big issue when talking about diversity, so I'd be curious to see the results.)

With all of the other questions about diversity on the survey, I'm surprised this one's not already on there.

With this data we could do interesting things like compare impostor-syndrome-ness across groups- maybe we're all more alike than we thought? Or maybe certain groups are more self-conscious or critical than others? Then if somebody smarter than me comes up with a good question to accurately determine the survey-taker's actual skill level, there are a ton of interesting comparisons we could make.

## **Reach Out**

I'd also like to see the survey taken by a more diverse group of people. Right now it is mostly focused on pretty active users of Stack Overflow. That makes for a good amount of self-selection- which is great if we're trying to survey users of Stack Overflow, but not so great if we're trying to survey the real world.

Anecdotally, I (used to) work at a place that does software prototyping for the government. We do very little web development. Most of my coworkers are over the age of 40, and they would never think to take a Stack Overflow survey. So most of the people and technologies I work with are not reflected in this data, and I would bet that most of the rest of the real world is not reflected either. And that's okay, but then I think it's a bit dishonest (and maybe even dangerous) to declare that JavaScript is the most popular language. The real world contains a lot more diversity, and not everybody is a web developer. It's not surprising that web technologies come out on top of an internet survey on a site that a lot of web developers visit. I'm not sure how much we can really extrapolate from that though.

I don't know what the solution to this problem is- maybe "brand" the survey a bit differently and "advertise" it on other sites a bit more? Maybe reach out to groups that might not normally take the survey? Saying something like "we're measuring tech trends across the entire computer science world, so get your voice heard" might be a bit more encouraging to non-SO-users than "take a Stack Overflow survey"?

## **Computer Science isn't just Ones and Zeroes**

This might just be my daydream of the day, but I'd also like to see questions that fight (or at least measure) the stigma of computer science as being "boring ones and zeroes". Maybe a couple questions like this:

- On a scale of 1 to 10, how much of your job is a math?
- On a scale of 1 to 10, how much of your job is a science?
- On a scale of 1 to 10, how much of your job is an art?
- On a scale of 1 to 10, how much of your job is a craft?
- On a scale of 1 to 10, how much of your job is fixing computers?

The results to this might be interesting, and might help dispel some of the misconceptions about what programming is? We could go a level deeper and ask "on a scale of 1 to 10, how much do **other people** think your job is ___?", but that might be a bridge too far.

Comment: I really like the imposter syndrome questions! Maybe the "Not Ones and Zeroes questions" could be reworded into one question "which of these words would you use to describe your craft?"...

Comment: Just sayin', I think the last set of questions you list should be on a scale of more than just 2 values.

Comment: @jinglesthula I don't really know what you mean, but note that I'm not recommending this exact wording. I'm just trying to get across the general idea of what I'd want to ask. I'm sure the survey team is much better at coming up with the actual questions than I am.

Comment: Sorry - just cracking wise ;) (though for consistent word size, if it is left as binary I'd recommend `01` rather than `1`)

Comment: @jinglesthula oh my god I *just* got it.

Comment: Obviously it should be "On a scale of 0h to Ah", to weed out any spies and project managers taking the survey.

Comment: @Lundin I really want to read that as "On a scale of Ohms to Amp-hours"...

Comment: "Computer Science isn't just Ones and Zeroes" And yet you gave "1 to 10" as the range.

Answer (score 49):

> How many hours do you actively work for in a day?

A work day generally has 8 hours. The question deals with average number of hours spent working actively on a project, in a day.

Comment: Conversely: "How many hours do you spend in meetings on a typical day?"

Comment: What is considered "actively working"? Just coding? Researching? Reading related articles and tutorials to help improve your skills in general? Thinking? Attending meeting that are part of your job? Many times I need to take a break from actual coding, and do something else while thinking a problem through in the back of my head, and I usually still consider that "working".

Comment: And here's something else, @ashish: I have 8 different bosses right now.

Comment: Maybe even throw in a question relating to how productive you are compared to your coworkers? Maybe a dumb question, since I'm sure most people think they are more productive.

Comment: If I'm not a professional programmer, am I supposed to interpret that as "How many hours do you spend at work every day?" (doesn't necessarily have anything to do with programming) or "How many hours do you spend programming every day?" (not necessarily for work)?

Comment: @JonSchneider The other way around as you put it does capture a subset of the possibilities.

Comment: @TotZam "actively working" could be defined as activities that directly contribute to your work. ( For e.g. Researching, brainstorming, sprint planning etc. ) What should not be considered for instance - Surfing the net ( not related to your work ), checking phone (social updates), playing games, catching up with office colleagues etc.

Comment: @DonaldDuck For anyone, time spent at work (office premises) everyday may not be necessarily equal to time spent on activities that directly contribute towards your responsibilities. The aim is to capture how much time do we actually put in towards our responsibilities that affect it directly.

Comment: @TravisJ Doesn't matter. It is about productivity. I work on two different projects every day which are with separate companies.

Comment: @ashish - ... it was a quote from Office Space about working and overtime.

Answer (score 47):

I think it would be interesting to see stats of [The Joel Test](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/):

> Do you use source control?
>   Can you make a build in one step?
>   Do you make daily builds?
>   Do you have a bug database?
>   Do you fix bugs before writing new code?
>   Do you have an up-to-date schedule?
>   Do you have a spec?
>   Do programmers have quiet working conditions?
>   Do you use the best tools money can buy?
>   Do you have testers?
>   Do new candidates write code during their interview?
>   Do you do hallway usability testing?

Potentially this could be rephrased to "You/your company".

Comment: I agree that it would be interesting, although lot of these don't even apply to some companies. The "Joel test" kind of assumes that everyone works in some mega corporation. It is not so relevant for smaller companies, consultants, students etc.

Comment: @Lundin I agree this wouldn't apply to 100% of developers. See the comment by  Donald Duck regarding optional corporate survey section.

Answer (score 45):

Ask about how many developers do more than one job. Apart from their 40 hours/week full time.

- Do they work as a freelancer too?
- Partime with another company?
- or just prefer to relax and spend time with friends and family
- Have startup side by side?
- Other Hobbies

Comment: Perhaps they also have a startup?

Comment: None of those 3. When I'm not working, I'm mostly spending my time on my hobbies. Family isn't a hobby ;-)

Comment: Perhaps they are a hacker by night. Searching for someone by name Morpheus...

Comment: Does raising kids count?

Comment: I would add an option for educational. i.e. online courses / distance learning etc

Answer (score 43):

> How often do you find yourself in multiple projects at your workplace?

I wanted to know whether it's common (like it's for me) to be switching among large projects daily/weekly.

Comment: Possibly add "At the same time"?

Comment: I feel like this could be broken down a bit more. I'm currently working on a single project where the work spans at least 5 different enterprise systems and a couple of dozen distinct programs. But it's all one project because it's building to a common goal.

Comment: @DarBrett Not really sure about that. I was referring specifically to working in multiple projects/clients/applications

Answer (score 41):

Either provide a way to resume the survey midway through, or put any work sensitive questions at the start.

In the past I've started answering it during build/deploy pauses and ended up having to abandon it when unable proceed without answering questions that I wasn't comfortable doing on a machine where my employer could be snooping.

Comment: Very good suggestion. Not really a topic, but it would be a big improvement of the Survey overall

Comment: We're looking into whether we can make this work.  In the meantime, can you tell me what questions you deem particularly work-sensitive?  Was it just the "satisfaction with current job" question, or something else?

Comment: @KevinTroy Probably both job satisfaction and the various job search ones.  Both contained information I would not have wanted the PHBs at my last job to know about.

Answer (score 40):

Here are few questions I would like to know answers for

> - Which type of editor theme do you use dark or light?
> - How often does your go for team lunch?
> - Does your company do code review after project is done?
> - If there is a small piece of code (1 or 2 lines) you found online and it is the first time you seeing that code, would you prefer to copy and paste code or write it by yourself?
> - Do you ever listen to music while working?

Comment: Thanks for inciting the *dark vs light theme* war. :P

Comment: And the followup - If you do listen to music, what genre?

Comment: "Do you ever listen to music while working?" -> Yes, often not by choice.

Comment: I use light theme for the code editor, but dark theme for the terminal (command line). I wonder if other people are split too, and we can turn that into two questions, or if it's meaningless...

Comment: `Do you ever listen to music (or another audio) while working`?, perhaps? Personally, I listen [Grand Theft Auto: Vice City Stories Vice City Public Radio (VCPR)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDYWoG-l5q4) and similar talk radio programs = pretty hilarious! :)

Answer (score 27):

In your editor/IDE of choice, do you use:

- text expansion/code snippets
- basic copy/paste keyboard shortcuts
- I lovingly type every character by hand

Comment: Could be interesting to correlate this with various other questions

Comment: I personally wouldn't know which of these to select. I largely eschew most IDE features and even copy/paste (“if there's repetion on such a level, it means the code is not high-level enough – potential for metaprogramming / DRY”); still I certainly don't _type every character_, making heavy use of tab-complete, auto-indent and typed-holes code deduction, not to speak of all kinds of Vim tricks.

Comment: Some good points.  How to phrase it is open to suggestion, for sure.  The main gist is along the lines of "where along the tools/productivity continuum do you fall for how you get the text characters into the files?"

Comment: Would code completion fall under text expansion? That should be made more obvious.

Comment: "How fast can you touch type?"

Answer (score 26):

> Are you programmer because of the passion or are you in it for the money?

Comment: Should include a "Both" Option, or better "On A Scale of 1 to 10"

Comment: Wait... it's possible to make _money_ by doing this??

Comment: Agreed with @BigM on "Both", especially combined with DonaldDuck's comment on the question - I use different languages between work and home, no almost overlap.

Comment: How about an Other option?

Answer (score 24):

I think it'd be good to ask about family. I'm not great at formulating questions but a few covering:

- Who do you live with (Alone/Parent/Partner/Colleague/Friend)?
- Do you have any children (No/1/2/3/4/5+)?
- Are your job choices influenced by family?

Comment: Very interesting!

Comment: Can we add pets do the list?

Comment: Aside from the last question, the first two seem too personal. Most of the survey is about your profession. Other than gender I'm not sure I would want SO to have such personally identifiable details.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I feel like the first two support the third. Then you get metrics like "Having more children -> family has more/less influence on jobs".

Answer (score 24):

We're not all web developers!

I've [posted this list last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319221/what-else-should-we-ask-developers/319305#319305) as a question suggestion:

> ### What do you deliver?
>
> - Web applications
> - Web services
> - Desktop applications
> - Server applications / daemons / background jobs
> - Mobile / tablet / handheld / wearable applications
> - Queries / ETL jobs / ...
> - Documentation
> - Machines
> - Environments
> - Pizza
> - Whatever I forgot to think of

I don't remember the options that were chosen (are [these](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#developer-roles) all you could select?), but please let us pick between more than "web developer" and "desktop developer". Not everyone develops user-facing software.

I mainly build Windows Services, daemons and ETL processes, which are neither desktop nor web applications.

Comment: Dreams. Coders deliver dreams...

Comment: And then there's those that don't 'deliver' the code they work on at all, they deliver the results of those codes (data science, algorithms, etc.)

Comment: Looking at the SW industry as whole, there's a large segment of devs that mainly deliver bugs and patches.

Answer (score 23):

> How many meetups/conferences do you participate in in a year?

I want to test my hypothesis. A meetup is just for a generalist, student, or early professional developer, but a highly specialized developer prefer using Stack Overflow or another international forum, because they can find some interesting topic (and capable people) by this forum.

Comment: *looks around the cornfield* Gonna go with 0 here. However, the general idea behind this seems relevant. Maybe instead of meetups in your city it could be something like: How many industry conferences do you attend in a year (PyCon, GitHub Universe, BlackHat, etc)?  Restricting it to "your city" is going to exclude people that are not in "the city" (any city), or in locations that don't get such events. Another note, many conferences have either live streams or post videos of the talks later. It may be important to include those too. Someone might not attend in person, but does watch later.

Comment: Suggestion accepted, for not limited to 'your city'. For live streams or post videos, is harder to count on yearly level.

Comment: I would be more specific and ask more measurable "during the last year".

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this, but I think that a regular MeetUp is very different to a full day-long or week-long conference.

Comment: The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums (see e.g. <http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115>) (fora?). They are think tanks (ref. <http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681>).

Comment: Conferences/live coding sessions/meetups/whatevers are a good place to network and see people you've worked with in the past. It's definitely a potentially valuable place to be for engineers of any experience level. Entertaining the idea that they are only about learning something new is missing half of the truth.

Answer (score 23):

> Are you mainly using legacy, outdated, up-to-date, new or bleeding
>   edge tech stacks?

A subjective question on whether we consider ourselves working on newer or older tech. stacks.

Comment: I like this question. But the definitions of "legacy", "outdated" and "bleeding edge" are subjective. I would prefer if it is worded in absolute terms. Something like: `Which was the release year of the technology stack you primarily work with?` with the options being something like: `Before 2000, 2000 - 2005, 2005 - 2010, 2010 to 2015, After 2015`.

Comment: I work primarily with Windows, so, let's see...release date was 1985. :-)

Comment: @NisargShah - The point is to be subjective I think.

Comment: @Ross haha I probably didn't read that second sentence. Though my point is, some of my coworkers don't find .net 4.0 outdated, while I do. Hence the answers about same technology stack might have different answers based of perception. So absolute answers would give better/reliable insights.

Comment: I think it'd need to be split for personal and work projects. I use newer technology at work than I do for personal work, but I assume most people would have the opposite

Comment: does having to support old (4.4) Android version count as using legacy tech stack?

Comment: @NisargShah The usual questions include what techs you use regularly, so this would be a way to figure out what people consider "outdated"/etc

Comment: @Izkata Most people work with multiple technologies. Say Java, MySql and Angular. Now when they call it outdated, you don't know which one they are talking about. Instead if they answered the year is 2002 - you don't need to know the technology.

Answer (score 22):

> Do you write code that others will end up running or using?
>
> Do you write code that others outside your organization will end up running or using?

I think of myself as not-really-but-kinda a "Developer" because I use this site even though nobody else really uses my code. I write plenty in the course of data analysis but all anybody ever sees from me is the analytic output. I'll take the survey but if anybody really cares about what "Developers" think, I should probably be excluded.

Answer (score 21):

**How happy are you with your job**, or just 'how happy are you' or something like that. Would be interesting to see what it co-occurs with (does the zen of Haskell make happy devs, do dynamically typed languages cause bug-induced nightmares), or hours worked etc.

Comment: And if they answer they aren't happy with their job, just drop them into the Jobs listing page when they click 'next'.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom yeah I did think maybe "Are you actively looking for a new job" would be a good proxy for happiness, but actually I know lots of people who hate their jobs but for various reasons aren't looking for a new one right now, or love their jobs but want to change for practical reasons etc

Comment: Unhappy with job might be the job itself is OK but the commute (or some other factor) is bad. So for both happy and unhappy: (1) when do you expect or plan to change jobs? (2) Will that be to another IT or programming job? (3) Will it be to totally different job? (4) Will it be retirement?

Comment: @LangeHaare Or - I've got my severance letter so I'm looking even though I wouldn't mind staying.

Answer (score 21):

> Are you willing to immigrate for a better job? 
>       - If so, where do you want to go to immigration? (US, UK, Singapore, etc)
>       - If you are willing to immigrate but have not been able to go yet, why? (Language, Culture, Family, etc)

I planned immigration for the job, and I joined a global company to do it, but I did not get an opportunity to work in the United States and I moved on to another company.
I wonder what other developers are doing.

Comment: +1 - I wonder if the questions could be reworded to make it more globally applicable. I'm a US developer, and I'd be willing to immigrate for a better job. Russian-speaking would be sweet. Also, would add as an option for 2nd bullet point - "not sure where to find such offers"

Comment: For readability, the question should probably ask if people are willing to *emigrate* to another country.

Comment: @DavidG wouldn't it actually be "emigrate from <home country>" in that case?

Comment: @Cat'r'pillar Without a specific country in mind, all you can ask is if someone is willing to emigrate from their current location.

Comment: @DavidG I was just being pedantic about the use of 'emigrate' :P sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 18):

**What mode of transportation do you use for your commute?**
(Select all that apply)

- I don't commute. <sub><sup>(I work where I live)</sup></sub>
- By foot
- Car
- Motorcycle
- Bicycle
- Train
- Tram
- Moped / Scooter
- Taxi
- Bus
- Airplane
- Boat
- Skateboard
- Skates / Rollerblades
- Quad
- Lorry
- Helicopter
- Segway
- Horse (& wagon)
- Blimp / Hot air balloon
- Submarine
- Dog sled
- Tank

**What's the distance of your daily commute?**
(Would probably need a miles and a km input, with some automated conversion.)

Comment: The list is a little short ;-)

Comment: I ski uphill both ways.

Comment: I'm going to make it my mission to be able to go to work by Segway, now that I think about it. Missing skates/rollerblades in the list as a more serious option - It's fast, fun and a great way to stay in shape.

Comment: Updated, @Gimby ^_^

Comment: What if tank and work from home equally apply? Did I won?

Comment: Glad to see [boat](https://www.chicagowatertaxi.com/) in the list

Comment: @Izkata ah, boats and programming... https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19487 for anyone not familiar :)

Answer (score 16):

I would be interested in knowing about secure coding practices being followed by the survey participants.

The questions could be something like this:

> Which of these secure coding practices do you follow?
>
> - Input type, range and length validation
> - White-listing allowed input values
> - Client + Server Validation
> - ...

It would be particularly interesting to see how these responses coorelate with reported experience, salary and primary programming language.

Comment: ... ● Automated coverage testing (QuickCheck etc.) ● Dependent/refinement types ● Encapsulated side-effects (e.g. monads) ● Virtualisation ...

Comment: This is highly application-specific, so I don't think the questions would be relevant. For example, I program industrial control systems. Security is not really a concern, apart from preventing copy-cats from stealing your product. Safety on the other hand, is a major concern.

Comment: @Lundin Good point. I was only thinking from the perspective of web development. The list might be way too big considering other aspects of programming. Probably grouping these secure coding techniques into basic, intermediate and advanced categories would be more efficient. But then there is still the challenge of phrasing the question in such a way to make these categories obvious.

Answer (score 16):

The survey currently asks for:

> Years Coding Professionally

But I'd also like to see something like:

> Years Coding Professionally *after* Undergraduate Education

The idea here is an attempt to differentiate a 10-years-professional-being-3-after-undergraduation from a 10-years-professional-after-undergraduation, which seems a relevant measure in terms of professional work time.

---

A potential caveat is that I'm not sure if it would be useful world wide - but in Brazil, for example, some programmers have started to work as technicians, hence that new measure would fit nicely.

Another potential caveat is that there are lots of great programmers that are self-taught or haven't completed/started undergraduate education yet that already works professionally - but I also do feel that it would be interesting to take a look into those cases to reveal the importance of formal education, in a different point of view.

Comment: "Undergraduation" is not actually a thing, so I believe you were referring to one's undergraduate education. On the other hand, "professionally" implies *not* in an educational setting, since it means you're getting paid, so...this clarification seems redundant.

Comment: One can be paid while working for college where he/she is studying. While it's a valuable experience, it's not always a "real world" experience.

Comment: @CodyGray Does professionally really implies on having a completed undergraduate education? In my case, for example, I work professionally (getting formally paid, having real world experience) since 2009 when I was just a technician in programming - and I completed formal education in 2013. You mean that I became a professional just in 2014? If so, I sincerely disagree.

Comment: No, it doesn't imply that you've *completed* it. Professional means that you're getting paid to do the job, so you were gaining professional experience when you started working, in the real world. It's totally possible to have a job before you start going to university. @falsarella

Comment: What about the vast majority (?) of people that *don't* have a degree (and aren't students) and *do* work as professional devs?

Comment: @Mat'sMug That's what I mentioned in the last paragraph.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't read it as implying self-taught at all.

Comment: And then there's students who work professionally (getting paid) in their free time/during summers.

Answer (score 16):

**Social Skills/Interactions Related -**

There is a public opinion that Programmers are not very social human beings.
[Citation Needed]

> Do you consider yourself Introvert/Extrovert/Socially Awkward ?

Comment: What is "Socially awkward" nowadays where everyone lives online through social media or in Whatsapp, I wonder.

Comment: @Gimby maybe "Socially awkward" is when you don't live online or use Whatsapp *like me*.

Answer (score 15):

> What is your caffeinated drink of choice

- None
- Espresso
- Americano
- Filter
- Instant
- Tea
- Cola (Caffeine content < 40mg)
- Energy drink (Caffeine content > 40mg)

It would be nice to associate different coding behaviours with each beverage, as in: 
[**pro·gram·mer (n) An organism capable of converting caffeine into code.**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Programmer)

Comment: Red Bull.... ;)

Comment: Generalise red bull to energy drinks I'd say. AKA sugar water.

Comment: Needs a "I don't drink caffeine option"

Comment: @AlexL not caffeinated is it

Comment: it's number one

Comment: As we all know, the definition of a programmer is: an organism capable of converting caffeine into code. So you can use this as a trick question to validate the test - anyone who picked "none" is clearly not a programmer, but some sort of spy, bot or project manager.

Comment: On a more serious note, I would be interested in knowing the amount of coffee a programmer consumes per work day.

Comment: @Lundin starbucks would pay for that

Comment: @eddyce well give em the information, hopefully they will start to sell actual coffee!

Comment: @Gimby upvote x 10

Answer (score 14):

How do you learn new languages/sharpen existing skills? Answer should be able to pick from more than one.

- University Classes
- Online University
- Books
- YouTube
- Online Courses (such as Udemy or Coursera)
- On-Job training
- Trial and Error
- Other:

It'd be interesting to see the correlation between experience, salary, etc. vs. what continued learning (if any at all) is done.

Perhaps a sub-question, if so desired, would be how many hours do you spend on a weekly basis doing the above tasks/learning?

Comment: How about the Documentation itself as a choice?

Comment: Repurposing some code-base, migrating From->To , where From is a known language and `To` is the new language, starting by writing test drivers for code produced by language experts.

Comment: Sharpening existing skills is primarily done through applying the skills you have; I.E. through working experience, solving realistic problems and making, learning from and correcting mistakes. This question seems to be primarily about learning new things so maybe just focus on that.

Comment: @Gimby, this may be a half truth. You can certainly sharpen skills by taking more advanced classes, with no "real world" experience. However, most classes that are worth taking walk through realistic examples. Also, "Trial and Error" and "On-Job Training" are some of the options in the list I provided

Comment: There's a site called Stack Overflow which could be added to the list.

Comment: I believe it has already been asked in the survey...

Answer (score 13):

I would like to know about remote work.

@Liam mentioned the subject, however I think it deserves separate focus.

> How many days per week are you allowed to work from home?
>   1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 / 6
>
> How many days per week do you usually work from home?
>   1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 / 6
>
> Are you paid the same rate remotely?
>   - Paid not hourly
>   - Same rate
>   - Different rate
>
> Subjectively, how does remote productivity compare to the office one?
>   - More productive remotely
>   - More productive in the office
>   - No significant difference

Answer (score 11):

*How much do each of the following factors affect your like/dislike of a programming language?*

- Syntax
- Available paradigms
- Lack of odd behaviors and quirks
- Available standard library / built-in objects
- Includable APIs / Quality of package ecosystem

---

Syntax might be further broken down into:

- concise
- elegant
- readable

but all these would need to be carefully defined, as their subjective meaning might vary wildly from person to person.

---

A further question might be: *How do you rate your liked/disliked programming language X, in each of the above categories?*

Answer (score 11):

**Beverage-related question**

> What drinks *(all kinds, maybe exclude coffee?)* do you usually drink to boost your mindset / logic power / to make you concentrate more?

Comment: 1) and 3) I believe are way too broad. I cannot really imagine how those could be fit into a few points, everyone has his/her own personal way for those. 2) is based on the false premise that everyone needs such things - many of us are okay with good old water.

Comment: Should I vote for this if I like question 1 but not 2 or 3?! Would make more sense if this was one suggestion per answer

Comment: @Liam Done converting the other two into separate answers

Comment: @Balazs I separated the other two, so please re-comment if you like

Comment: an option could be = none.

Answer (score 11):

**Include Delphi/Object Pascal**

In every survey I've seen so far there was no mention of Delphi/Object Pascal. Given that it is consistently ranked in the [top 20 most popular languages](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/) it should be included in the survey languages list, especially since I've seen far less popular languages included.

Answer (score 11):

Are your working hours relaxed or does your company enforces strict working hours ..?

Answer (score 9):

I would be interested to learn more about the Management. For example:

1. **What do you/your company use to plan programming projects:**

   - Blackboard
   - Notebook / Drawing block
   - MS Office
   - Online software (web-applications):
   - Desktop / Server applications:
   - Some another method

For example we can do deeper. If using MS Office, specify a current product:

```
- Excel
- Project
- Project Server
```

If web:

```
- Jira
- Slack
- GanttPro
- Trello
- Another one (blank line for filling)
```

And If desktop:

```
- Gemini
- Redmine
- Smartsheet
- Another one (blank line for filling)
```

We can put all of them into one question but then it be cumbersome.

---

2. **And the second idea - what is about software development methodology:**

   - "Traditional"

     - Prototyping
     - Waterfall
     - Incremental
     - RAD
     - Spiral
     - Rational Unified Process
   - Agile

     - Scrum
     - Kanban
     - DSDM
     - Extreme programming
     - Feature driven development
     - Lean software development

I know this type of questions has problems: there are too many different applications and methods, but even choosing some category give an awesome output - It is really interesting and actual topic.

If there is no any limits of number of questions we can create tree structure for questions and use a lot of applications and methods. Also we can include some mixing (for example someone can use not only one method but combine  several).

Comment: Planning? who needs planning!

Comment: @KevinB my superiors need... :D

Comment: I believe this was supposed to be a survey for programmers.

Comment: @Lundin In principle, we can separate the questions for programmers and non-programmers (depending on the first question, the following questions will differ: for non-programmers I will indicate typical programs too). Everyone uses some planning system.

Answer (score 9):

> Have you seen or experienced sexism in your workplace?

I would like to see some questions in this vein. It is especially relevant with the #metoo hashtag in high circulation. The technology sector is especially infamous for this behavior, and it would be interesting to see if there is a discrepancy between perception of this between genders.

Comment: Sexism, homophobia, racism... All valid

Answer (score 8):

> Do you prefer a closed office plan or an open one?
>
> What does your company support, open or closed?

Comment: _"What does your company support?"_ is quite vague...

Comment: I meant open vs closed, as a continuation of the same

Comment: I believe there's already lots of scientific research about this. Not quite sure what a somewhat unscientific internet survey would add to that debate. Unsurprisingly, people prefer their own, quiet offices.

Comment: @Lundin Not everyone, open plans are useful for teams that are heavy on collaboration.  The interesting point this survey would be able to add is if there's any correlation between preferring open plans and specific responses to other questions.

Comment: @Lundin I believe this would also be helpful in helping industry align more with developer preferences and may help in reducing churn rate in future.

Answer (score 8):

I loved the debate recently on the *Tabs or Spaces* answer so how about:

> Portrait or Landscape
>
> Do you have you main monitor in portrait or landscape orientation?

Comment: I like asking about it, but this wording requires me to figure out whether my portrait or my landscape monitor is the "main" one, if I have one of each. (Which I don't at the moment, but I have in the past.)

Answer (score 7):

> On a scale of one to ten (one meaning low correlation, ten meaning high correlation), how closely do you relate coffee intake to the quality of code produced?

Comment: could be generalized to caffeine (some devs probably do energy drinks but not coffee).  Also, it may be good to simply ask about caffeine intake and code quality as separate questions and then correlate, as opposed to asking about the devs' perception of the correllation.  Too, some people may answer this question with a 10 meaning more coffee === worse code, and others may give a 10 meaning more coffee === better code, so in its present form the ambiguity may not produce meaningful answers.

Comment: @jinglesthula I'm sure there are better ways of posing the question. That's a job for smarter people than I; however I _was_ specifically aiming for the developer's perception rather than actual correlation (which would be much harder to reliably correlate in a meaningful way).

Comment: haha - gotcha. :) I think still it may be ambiguous, as some may relate intake to quality going up, and others to it going down. Is there a way to phrase it so that all answers that are the same also mean the same thing? If 95% of people answer 10, that means that we generally agree that intake has either a strong positive *or* a strong negative correlation. This may be less interesting than asking if people feel their code quality is a) better, b) worse, or c) unaffected by caffeine. Alternatively, you could pair this with a 2nd question about it making quality go up or down, which solves it.

Comment: Too many variables in this one. "Coffee", what is that even? There are many types of coffee that all give different reactions; some are better for people prone to high blood pressure for example. Do you take it with sugar/milk and how much/what kind. Age, DNA, weight, if your stomach is neutral - it all weighs in on how coffee affects you as a person and thus how it might affect your work. The more interesting question I think is: how does it affect your work when you drink energising drinks (coffee, black tea, cola, fruit juice, etc.) versus drinking only caffeine and sugar free drinks?

Answer (score 7):

I would absolutely love to know more about developers' relationship with version control. Which systems they use, how competent they are with them, how they learned to use them, that sort of thing.

---

Some context for my suggestion:

I recently got my bachelor's in software engineering from Mississippi State University. It wasn't until my very last semester that I realized that literally nothing in the coursework or lectures touched upon version control, or really even nudged students toward even looking into it on their own. It was just a skill I had picked up while working on my own personal projects and getting involved in open source. This means that a lot of students just don't learn about it, which sucks. I had to spend a not-insignificant amount of time at the beginning of nearly every group project giving people a crash course in git, and looking back, I'm actually kind of surprised it took me until my last semester to see the pattern. This was even the case for my senior project group, who were all second semester seniors.

I thought this was probably a problem specific to my institution, but upon getting a job and moving out of state, I have learned that this is not the case. I am very interested to know if version control's absence in the curriculum is a widespread problem.

Comment: They asked about [version control software of choice](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#work-version-control) and [frequency of check-ins](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#checking-in-code) on this past survey. What additional information do you want to know? "Competence" is a difficult question to ask, because people have a hard time judging their own competence.

Comment: @CodyGray I have added some context to my suggestion. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Well, yeah. Your experience is not altogether surprising. Universities are not trade schools. Their intention is not to teach you how to program. They teach you computer science. They are rather different sets of skills, although one certainly helps with the other. Version control software is not typically taught as part of a comp sci curriculum at universities, but that doesn't mean professional software developers don't use it. Of course they do. It's just something that new hires have to pick up during the onboarding process, if they aren't already familiar with it from open-source projects

Comment: Again, not sure how that contextual information would translate into a question. The only thing I'm seeing here is, how did you learn to use version control software? But that's not going to be altogether different from the general question of, how do you learn new tools/technologies, which has been asked/answered on several prior surveys. The top answers by far are books and Stack Overflow. We've lots of questions about git, for example, which is the most popular version-control software by miles, according to the last survey. :-)

Comment: As for competence @CodyGray, perhaps targeted questions like "Do you/your team use feature branches?"

Answer (score 7):

3 questions:

1. When do you ask a question on stackoverflow?
2. When do you answer a question on stackoverflow?
3. When do you look for an answer or browse stackoverflow?

Each has categories such as:

- While at work
- While on work breaks
- While commuting
- While at home during "non sleep" hours
- Late at night when I should be sleeping

Each category the options:

- never
- rarely
- sometimes
- often
- a lot

Comment: 4. When Stack Overflow is down, do you have to stop working until it is back up?

Answer (score 7):

Given the continuing problems in this area in general (Equifax anyone?), I'd love to see stats on this

> How does your company handle (cyber)security and/or security audits within your applications?
>
> - We have dedicated a staff/employee who handles security
> - Members of the team each have an area of security they are responsible for
> - We don't dedicate time to security, but we try to incorporate security practices as best as we can
> - Ain't nobody got time for security #YOLO

Comment: There should probably be a "not applicable" option for industries that don't handle sensitive data.

Comment: Ask this question to the company that programs the microcontroller inside your electric toothbrush. Zero security breaches, it is almost as if it isn't connected to the internet!

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to see some question that addresses developer's confidence in what they are working on. Something like...

> How confident are you that your current project will meet its objectives?

Given that the majority of [software projects are challenged or fail](https://www.infoq.com/articles/standish-chaos-2015), I think this is an interesting measurement to capture on its own, as well as correlating with other variables. 
It would definitely say something about our industry if the majority of developers felt that it would be a significant challenge for their team to meet their objectives...

Comment: I think that's going to be misleading. I'd imagine that confidence has more to do with leadership and resources than whether or not I'm using a specific technology stack.

Comment: @Andy, I agree with you. I would hope to see that there isn't a correlation. Needless to say, correlation does not mean causation.

Comment: What if my current project is tanking, but it's the rare exception?  (or vice versa)

Comment: @jinglesthula, good point! Perhaps the question could capture the developers confidence that their team / company will meet their objectives?... Or it could ask about their last most significant project?

Comment: It looks like a handful of people have downvoted this questions and upvoted @Andy's concern that this question is misleading. I don't believe there is anything misleading about collecting this information, only in the way it could be interpreted; and that is true with any survey... But, if this question is out of scope, then by all means, let's leave it out!

Comment: Your question is great. I think it should be on the survey. It helps showing if we are in our current position because we believe in our project/leaders or just for the money/comfort zone.

Answer (score 5):

Last year asked about AngularJS.  It seems it would be appropriate to differentiate between AngularJS (1.x) and Angular (2+).

I suspect some who answered AngularJS actually use the more modern framework, so lumping them together doesn't give a clear picture.

Comment: For those downvoting, I am curious about the benefit of combining them (or of giving the impression the newer framework isn't represented).  SO Trends paints a partial/vague picture of the two over time, but it would be great to see what people report they are actually using.

Answer (score 5):

I posted this following question as comments but now posting as question to see if community wants this:

> How many hours of sleep you get every night?

[Research shows](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/sleep-deprivation-epidemic-health-effects-tired-heart-disease-stroke-dementia-cancer-a7964156.html) just how important sleep is. Also in Japan [death from overworking is common](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/world/woman-japan-dies-overwork-common-death-article-1.3542948).

Also, another question which I find important:

> Do you have a standing desk at you workplace?

[This](http://www.cnn.com/2017/09/11/health/sitting-increases-risk-of-death-study/index.html) and [this](http://www.latimes.com/science/sciencenow/la-sci-sn-sitting-death-risk-20170911-story.html) articles say that sitting for more then 30 minutes causes early death. Perhaps we could relate presence of standing desks to overall well-being. (I worked in both places with and without standing desks and standing desk really made a difference for me).

I am hoping to see more health related questions in general.

Comment: _"sitting for more then 30 minutes causes early death"_ > CNN and LA Times are credible sources. Both mention _"early death"_, but fail to define it... All in all, rather vague.

Comment: I agree that's vague. [Here is article](http://annals.org/aim/article/2653704/patterns-sedentary-behavior-mortality-u-s-middle-aged-older-adults) which CNN links to and it has some numbers (which I frankly didn't entirely understand when I first glanced at it) but it looks like some serious research. (Regardless, sitting for a long time causes me back pain :)  ).  [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/541/)

Comment: [very relevant](https://xkcd.com/1329/)

Answer (score 5):

I'd be interested in *human* languages (i.e. English, German, Russian, Mandarin…).

- Are developers more multilingual than non-developers?
- Are developers who are more multilingual than their peers more successful? more productive? more educated?
- Just how many developers around the world only speak English?

I suppose taking the survey in English would bias the sample somewhat.

Answer (score 5):

> How much emphasis does your company or team place on best practices, standards, unit testing?

I'd forego beer carts, paid meals, happy hours, etc., in favor of a company that's serious about keeping technical debt to a minimum.

Answer (score 4):

To what extent do you agree that the management of your company are open to advices and opinions of its developers when making a decision? For example, when trying to win a project tender, are they hearing the opinions of those who would actually be carrying it out or do they only consider the possible revenue?

Answer (score 4):

Let's learn about the SO users who work in Education.

> Do you teach/Have you ever taught Programming, CS or IT?
>
> At what level? (HS, College, Post-grad, Other)
>
> How many students per year?

This question can be important in understanding many, many questions we get from confused students who are unwilling (or unable) to ask their teachers.

Comment: Have you ever taught Programming, CS, or IT? I used too.

Comment: Not really. I am thinking about it now, though. My kids are in college now, studying Software Engineering, and the quality of the teachers is a mixed bag at best.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I meant that as a question for the survey. As in: Do you/Have you ever taught Programming, CS, or IT? :)

Answer (score 4):

**Family-related question**

> If you are a full-time developer *(not a freelancer)*, how do manage your time between coding and bonding with family / friends / etc, especially if deadline is near?

Comment: some freelancer's time is more full than some `full-time` developers, and the latter probably explains the former.

Answer (score 4):

> Do you use UML?

I'm taking a course that places heavy emphasis on UML modelling. The professor and the textbook suggest that UML is "standard" and "widely used" by software companies and developers, but [we students are skeptical!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803/is-uml-practical)

A [2013 survey of 50 developers](http://oro.open.ac.uk/35805/8/UML%20in%20practice%208.pdf), reported that "the majority of informants (35/50) do not use UML." It would be interesting to see if this holds for a larger sample size.

Comment: Lots use something similar to UML but not quite as strict. As in, you draw up all the things that your program should contain: modules/classes. Then you draw the dependencies (x uses y, or x inherits y). This doesn't have to be formal. Some things like use-cases of UML is really just a fancy word of applying some common sense and think in advance about what your product will do. It is really just a pre-study thing before you write the specification. So many might use design practices that a very similar to UML, but not formally UML.

Answer (score 4):

**What platform or technology decisions did you make this year, and either regret or find well made?**

This year, I personally took a huge gamble to go with an Angular + Material based project, totally getting outside of my personal comfort zone of RoR. It's been great, and I've learned a lot, and I'm glad for the decision.

But on the other hand, I could totally see having made a huge mistake, and thinking, "If I'd just gone with RoR I'd be done by now, and not spending my time wondering what I should have done."

I'm curious then about who else made this leap of faith, and did well, or failed.

Comment: I like this question a lot but would maybe rephrase it to be non-time based or maybe "within the past 5 years".  I unfortunately have not had the same experience as you going the Angular route.  It's an excellent library but me suggesting that a PHP app be completely rewritten to primarily use Angular has turned into a 2+ year effort that I was hoping would be done withing 1/2 a year.

Comment: Funny you mention PHP as that was the original project's code base.  I saw Ruby on Rails as a big leap forwards, but now see that Angular was a somewhat bigger leap forward, and definitely a leap sideways.  I still think that Ruby on Rails deals with database schemas and models far better, but in our case we had a ton (350 gig a day tons) of existing data structures and PL/SQL on an Oracle database to work with, so weren't starting from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for work, rate the top three reasons you would consider changing jobs:

1. The money
2. The benefits (medical, vacation time)
3. Non-financial perks (free lunch, on-site spa, etc.)
4. The technology the company uses
5. The products / services the company makes
6. The people I would be working with
7. If the company supports open source
8. "Culture"
9. Work-life balance
10. Commute distance and / or remote working capability

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to ask how many monitors other developers use, or maybe what resolution the monitors they use are

Answer (score 3):

> How do you correlate your code project with your level of happiness?
>
> Is your project the metric of your life fulfillment?

Answer (score 3):

Line up your = signs or don't make the reader use a sheet of paper to figure out which line on the right goes with which line on the left.

```
var i                       = 1;
var x                       = 2;
var aReallyLongVariableName = 3;
```

or

```
var i = 1;
var x = 2;
var aReallyLongVariableName = 3;
```

Comment: i'm curious, from a data science/analysis perspective - what hypothesis do you have about this question? do you think it will correlate to anything?

Comment: I think it will relate to age and / or primary computer language, but I'm not sure of either of those.  The older SQL users at my current company use it, but I never really have.  They also use the insert key and I don't, so it could correlate to "Do you use the insert key often on your keyboard?"  I'm also curious, in this visual age, if the nicer looking format of lining up the equal signs or the easier to type format of not bothering wins?  Could it possibly correlate to how important long term maintenance is when writing code?

Comment: I use both *sometimes*.

Answer (score 3):

> If you have immigrated for work, have you (tick all that apply):
>
> - Immigrated from a Developed Country to another Developed Country
> - Immigrated from a Developed Country to a Developing Country
> - Immigrated from a Developing Country to a Developed Country
> - Immigrated from a Developing Country to another Developing Country
> - None of the above.

The question of classification of "developed" and "developing" is tricky, but people have a general idea of the meanings.

It would be interesting to see how languages and technologies have influenced jobs and immigration. For example, do we see people skilled in new languages moving towards typical centers for innovation, or do we see them moving to countries that are still developing and looking to get ahead of the curve?

Comment: After your question, we could have a next one: "Was it worth immigrating? Are you happier now?"

Answer (score 2):

Going off of @Swellar's question:

> What are developers using to stay focused and boost concentration

I know I will listen to music, go for regular short walks, and make sure to have snacks handy throughout the day.  I'd be curious to hear what other developers do to help them concentrate on the work at hand.

Comment: It should be a open answer or pick some options?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I'm not sure what would be best; the request only asked for ideas, not specific questions, so I hadn't given the format much thought

Answer (score 2):

**Job Switch Related**

Did you move to, or away from, software development?

Options could include

- Moved into software development from directly related field (dev/ops, CM, support, etc)
- Moved into software development from indirectly related field (dev/ops, CM, support, etc)
- Moved into software development from something completely different (art, marketing, sales, etc)
- Moved from software development to directly related field (dev/ops, CM, support, etc)
- Moved from software development into indirectly related field (project management, systems engineering, etc)
- Moved from software development into something completely different (art, marketing, sales, etc)

It would be interesting to see the in/out flow of software developers/engineers between fields

Answer (score 2):

It'd be nice to see a series of questions about how employers help professional growth/development such as:

Does your employer

1. support/sponsor participation in attending conferences, workshops, seminars
2. subscribe to and make available online learning services
3. support/sponsor certificate or degree programs
4. assign a mentor to check in with you regularly and provide guidance
5. formally identify/outline an individualized career development plan

Answer (score 2):

It would also be interesting to know how many developers had to take a skills assessment for their current position.

And if they did, what that skills assessment might have been comprised of; was it

- coding test in the form of conceptual/academic questions
- coding test in the form of being asked to write code to address a particular set of criteria
- performing a code review
- completing a q/a or debug exercise
- development/delivery of a micro-project
- other

Answer (score 2):

When do you find yourself more productive -

A) while working alone

B) while working in a team as a non-lead

C) while working in a team as a leader

Or
Rate your productivity (on a scale of 1-10) in the 3 situations.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be interesting to see how developers get access to the paid tooling that they might need in different regions, languages, etc.

> Does your company provide all of the tooling (IDE, cloud subscriptions, etc.) that you need to complete your work? If not, how much of your own money have you paid for software development tools in the past year?
>
> - My company pays for it all
> - I exclusively use free tools
> - Less than $50
> - $50 - $100
> - $100 - $200
> - More than $200

Answer (score 1):

I've been wondering about the diversity of computer languages that individual developers must deal with.  So something along the lines of:

> - What do you consider to be your primary (preferred?) computer language(s)?
> - What other computer languages must you use to perform your job duties?

I'm guessing that people are motivated to be expert, or at least very good, with their primary or preferred language(s)).

My experience suggests that people must also deal with a number of other languages, which they are less invested in, in order to do their job.  When dealing with these languages folks open the editor, get the job done as quickly as they can, and call it good.

For individual languages, I think knowing the relative ratio of these two kinds of language users ("motivated to be expert" vs "just getting my job done") would be very useful information for the designers of those computer languages.

I've looked, but I've not found similar computer language use statistics.

Answer (score 1):

How many hours coding do you do each weekday and weekend day for: your main job, your second job/hobby (both or either).

If > 10 hours per day, what routines do you use to keep productive?

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to know what build tools do people use?

Comment: Only if the list of possible answers include "I don't" and "What is a build tool?".

Comment: @usr2564301 I agree :)

Answer (score 0):

How the work is defined among the developers.

For example:

1. **smaller companies** expects developer to do everything from ui design, html mocks, javascript framework and backend framework suitable for project and database.
2. **Fortune 500 companies** expects their employees to the subject matter expect on what they passionate and hired particularly for a specific technology.

How the quality of the software will be defined in both the above cases.

In other field like medical.

For example:
We cannot expect a passionate heart surgeon to do a successful kidney transplantation. Why not in software industry?

Comment: I know of companies with as little as 3 people that have a dedicated back-end programmer... This isn't really related to company size.

Comment: @Cerbrus you know of. But i had worked in company of strengh 3 people. I was a php developer who suppose to work with end to end application development from front end to back end. I disagree your comment.

Comment: @Mohan I've worked a number of different jobs through my career as a web developer. In some roles I've just been server-side code with maybe a little bit of database. Others server side and front end with no database involvement, and others I've been required to be full-stack. The requirements on the developer vary with the varying requirements of the job

Answer (score 0):

Regarding delivering code on time or ahead of schedule...

- What factors have repeatedly helped you?
- What factors have repeatedly hindered you?
- Have you found frameworks and/or libraries to primarily
  be a help or hindrance to your ability to deliver code on time or
  ahead of schedule?

Comment: Too open-ended.

Answer (score 0):

My question suggestion is:

> If you use Git for version control, what client do you use?
>
> - Git Bash
> - Git GUI
> - Tortoise Git
> - Source Tree
> - some plugin in your IDE
> - any other...

Comment: Another option: SmartGit

Answer (score 0):

- If you are a software developer, will you ever want to be a project
  manager in future.
- If you are a project manager who shifted from software developer profile, my question is "do you enjoy your job or the 'software developer' thing gave you more of a relief and satisfaction?"

Comment: Additional 
 - What do you suggest to someone for future.

Answer (score 0):

Is P = NP?

If the developer answers "no" they get permabanned.

Comment: Why would they be permabanned when P is obviously not equal to NP?

Comment: It shows they dont get it. P = NP, even Matt groening knew this.

Comment: Where's your proof?

Comment: it is yet to be proven but have faith it will come, there are people working on it, trust us.

Comment: _"Have faith"_ usually doesn't convince programmers. Try again, @DenizC.

Comment: It seems that for `N=1`, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about the UI language preference developers have for their tools (such as IDE / browser / notepad / Office):

- This question discusses the localization settings for tools you use:

  - The language of the tools I use matches my native language (English).
  - The language of the tools I use matches my native language (non-English).
  - Tool localization is usually available for my native language, but I prefer English.
  - Tool localization is usually unavailable for my language, though I would prefer English anyway.
  - Tool localization is usually unavailable for my language, I would use it had it existed.
  - My setting depends on the tool.
  - Can't decide // don't know // prefer not to answer.

Followup:

- If setting depends on the tool, please choose the reason(s):

  - My workplace / local IT department enforces working with a certain language.
  - Official documentation or similar resources is very limited or not available in my native language.
  - There is no online community to support the tool in my native language, or information is relatively scarce.
  - I don't like the translations in some of the tools.

Answer (score 0):

Same questions as [Remote Work](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#remote-work) but for working on geographically dispersed teams. Also asking:

- How many countries in the team?
- Time difference on the team?
- How does time difference impact your working hours?

Answer (score 0):

What causes you to **RAGE** most at work (checkboxes)?

- Manager
- Software that I am using
- Silly deadlines
- Existing code left by junior contractors
- Peers that take their shoes off with smelly feet
- Creative Company structure
- Juggling projects

Answer (score -1):

**Work-related question**

> What do you usually do if you are losing concentration, getting bored when coding a certain part of the program / system / etc?

Comment: I go to [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score -1):

Do you like pineapple on pizza? Yes/No

Justification: This is a very polarising question. I would like to know the percentage of programmers who are misguided on this point.

Comment: I like pizza on my pineapple.

Comment: We're all living in 2017, you're living in 3017.

Answer (score -1):

*About quality assurance practices*

**Do you do in your projects:**

1. Unit testing?
2. Integration testing?
3. Automated UI testing?
4. Manual UI testing?
5. Static code analysis?
6. Continuous integration?
7. Code coverage enforcing rules

*Inspired by "Do you do unit testing?" question from JetBrains DevEcosystem survey (https://www.jetbrains.com/research/devecosystem-2017/)*

Or:

How important are to you:

1. Unit tests?
2. Integration tests?
3. Automated UI testing?
4. Manual UI testing?

Another option might be to ask about code coverage developers are targeting (e.g. 90+ %) or if they even have at all this particular type of tests.

Comment: Define "important". Everyone in their right mind would like to have at least the first three.

Comment: @CodeCaster Then maybe we should ask how much time they invest into each of those?
I know from JetBrains survey that for example not all developers write unit tests: https://www.jetbrains.com/research/devecosystem-2017/

Answer (score -1):

1) Are you working from your **Home Town**?

2) If not then, Did you relocated to **another town within your home country**?

3)  If not then, Did you relocated to **another country**?

In your entire career, How many times did you relocate cities for better Job opportunities.

It will be interesting to know how its difficult to relocate across different cities/countries with/without family to get better Job opportunities and how its frequent/common in todays days.

Answer (score -2):

- How often do you socialize with engineering coworkers?
- How often do you socialize with non-engineering coworkers?
- What "soft" skill could you improve that would most likely improve your career?

  - Communications
  - Listening
  - Interviewing

Answer (score -2):

Maybe an interesting question:

> Do you think the modern design principles and concepts are good or evil?
>
> - SOLID/DI/IoC/you-name-it is the Holy Bible (aka Cargo cult)
> - I'm trying to follow the most (the relevant) ones, but sometimes there is a better way
> - KISS & YAGNI all the time!
> - What are design principles? I do Google driven development.
> - Please send me teh codez.

Background: there are many opinions, and it seems that even such *solid* things as SOLID are being criticized by some experienced developers or architects. It would be interesting to know whether the SO community rather follows the "law" or writes the code "from the heart".

Answer (score -2):

Maybe ask about prefered working environment?
Like co-worker (even we know we don't always have co-workers we like), or like working desk and the room, or maybe how's the office's coffee machine.

Answer (score -2):

> what tools do you use for your coding ?

Comment: A real programmer uses [butterflies](https://xkcd.com/378/).

Comment: Such an open-ended question can only be met with an open-ended answer: "I use programming tools".

Answer (score -3):

Is universal design and accessibility of user interfaces important?
What is your own maturity with design and development using any IT accessibility standards? 
What is your opinion on the maturity of your team and organization?

Either 
**websites**: Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG);
**Authoring tools**: Authoring Tool Accessibility Guidelines (ATAG);
**Browsers**: User Agent Accessibility Guidelines (UAAG);
**Web applications**: Accessible Rich Internet Applications (WAI-ARIA);
**or organizationally developed processes for user interface evaluation of accessibility** with a specific standard such as U.S. Access Board Standards ('Section 508') e.g., 
https://www.access-board.gov/guidelines-and-standards or test processes built upon those standards https://www.dhs.gov/publication/dhs-section-508-compliance-test-processes ?

Comment: This should be multiple answers, not a single. It is impossible to vote on each suggestion when you combine them.

Comment: Fair point. I guess I struggled with responding to request for ideas to add to the survey and ensuring they are asked together in relation to the same topic. I thought the goal was feedback and StackOverflow team would consider and reformat.

Answer (score -3):

- Have you detected & spotted early signs of burnout and managed to
  avoid it?
- How do you avoid more sidejobs or overtime thrown on you that leads
  to tech.debt and further burnout?

Comment: What's "burnout"? Answers would be very subjective

Answer (score -3):

Are non-work related questions allowed? Almost evrey programmer I meet is investing in cryptocurrency. I wonder how large that percentage really is...

Comment: Also lots of non-programmers invest in cryptocurrency by the way, if you have disposable income you have freedom to play with it. As a programmer I would be more interested in the backbone behind cryptocurrencies: blockchains. Is the technique being applied in projects, and how?

Answer (score -3):

What is the best Database as a Service (PaaS) that currently exist for a developer?

Answer (score -3):

I think it would be really interesting to ask.

> How would you describe your political orientation?
>
> - left
> - mid-left
> - mid-right
> - right

I would be interested in correlating this with the developers role/languages.

Comment: • somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score -4):

> Do you run your own business?

Like a small SaaS or something unrelated to IT. A very interesting topic, but doubt it will fit in a single question.

Answer (score -5):

> Are you 100% self-taught or do you own most of your programming skills from school?

Answer (score -7):

In the Frameworks, Libraries, and Other Technologies section can we include Redux as an option?

Comment: Reason for downvotes? I'll point out as a proxy for popularity that redux has more stars on github than angular https://github.com/reactjs/redux vs https://github.com/angular/angular. I'd think that leans it towards being significant enough for inclusion.

Answer (score -7):

What login/password practices do you have to put up with where you work?

- All SSH keys, baby!
- Cool rules because we have MFA.
- Rules, OMG so many dumb rules.
- None, please own us. Again.
- No standards, anarchy and chaos reign.

Answer (score -8):

Do you use the "Insert" key on your keyboard?

I wonder if this is an age thing, a primary computer language thing, an editor thing, or if you typically write or deal with code where all the equal signs are expected to line up?

Comment: What does the Insert key have to do with equal signs lining up?

Comment: Because people who line up the equals signs (or other items in their code) typically use the overwrite mode to change a variable name, instead of, say, double clicking on the name to delete it and then typing the new name.

Comment: That doesn't really fit with my experience. I personally line up everything that can possibly be lined up, because it helps me to catch syntax errors (not to mention looks neater and satisfies my OCD), but I've *never once* used overwrite mode. If possible, I disable it in my editor, because it stops me from inadvertently turning it on when going for the Delete key. Point being, if you want to ask about lining up assignments, then ask about that. What you've got here is [an X-Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Insert? My code won't compile unless _scroll lock_ is on, that's how old my stuff is.

Comment: I can't seem to find this key on my mac keyboard.

Answer (score -9):

For example:

> Do you got Abs?

I'm interested to if any developer is also takes workouts seriously!

Comment: Yes, I've got ABS in my car and in my motorcycle...

Answer (score -12):

> Does your company/team bring croissant (or any breakfast-like pastry)? If yes, how often? Who brings/pays for it?

I'm a junior developer and I worked in 3 different companies, two of them bring croissant/chocolat croissant every Friday (I live in France), and in the third, which was a big company, only my team brought it, also every Friday.

I'm curious about if it is a thing in France or if it also exists in other countries, or if I'm just lucky to have these breakfasts time three times in a row.

Comment: Although croissants in France are awesome, me personally I don't consider it lucky that you get offered the same type of junk food repeatedly. At least here in the Netherlands they mix it up and give you different kinds of artery-clogging sources of happiness ;)

Answer (score -19):

> How much do the following describe your code, on a scale of 0x0 to 0xF:
>
> - Structure: Sloppy to Neat
> - Function, variable and class names: One Or Two Letters to Helpful
> - Comments: None/Witty Remarks About Your Code to Almost Every Line

Other possible scales?

Comment: Of course nobody writes unreadable spaghetti code, they are only somehow... produced. But nothing writes them. ;-) Good question, formulating the answer would be useful for the programmers themselfes.

Answer (score -29):

> How much would you be willing to pay for a 13" laptop with a passive
>   e-ink display that is fully readable under direct sunlight

:) ehmm this is for lenovo, hp, apple etc.

Comment: This isn't really a good metric for developers. Some are more stingy than others, and not everyone needs this kind of thing, because they work indoors, where it can be dark and air-conditioned.