# Take the 2018 Developer Survey

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2018

**[Edit: The survey is now closed]**

It’s that time of year again—the annual developer survey is now open!

The survey will be open for three weeks starting today, and will tentatively close on January 26th.

As in previous years, anonymized results of the survey will be made publicly available under the Open Database License. We encourage you to download and analyze the dataset yourself when it becomes available.

On that note, throughout the survey, certain answers you and your peers give will be treated as personally identifiable information, and therefore kept out of the anonymized results file. We'll call out each of those in the survey with a note saying "This information will be kept private."

We've made this year's survey short (and by short we mean somewhat-freaking-long), but we've done our absolute best to be respectful of the time you're giving by taking the survey. If you have any questions or feedback in general, we'd love to hear it, just post an answer or comment as you deem appropriate. Thanks again to everyone, and happy new year!

[Take the Survey Now](https://stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/start/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=meta&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2018-collection)

Comment: I'm looking forward to seeing the results again this year. P.S I liked the section on asking us if we're worried about Skynet.

Comment: You lost me at "should take about 30 minutes"... is this survey aimed at the unemployed?

Comment: I received the email linking to the survey, which isn't hosted by SO. Wouldn't it be better to link to the SO page so that we can check it's legit ? Right now there's no obvious way to check that from using just the mail. Am I the only one a little cautious on the internets?

Comment: It's a shame that a lot of the questions are limit to preset answers such as the 'importance' ones. I was unable to complete it due to all answers being completely out of line with my *answer*.

Comment: Who is the survey for and for what purpose?

Comment: @DenysSéguret the link in the email goes to a stackoverflow.com URL, but then is redirected to the survey tool we're using. We had to use an external survey tool this time around and could not host it on our own site, unfortunately.

Comment: @RachelFerrigno It looks like it is a link to stackoverflow.email (which is also the source of the mail, and whose ownership for the common developer is harder to check)

Comment: There really should be more frequently a "I have no idea how to answer that" especially when the question is US culture oriented or any other reason the question feels very alien to your activity.

Comment: I think the "Somewhat Disagree/Agree" order is different between questions.

Comment: *“How many monitors are set up at your workstation?”* – At home, I have a *very large* monitor that is bigger than my multi-monitor setup at work. So this question does not really tell much about the work environment. It should rather ask for the total pixel space or something.

Comment: @poke "How much square meter/inch monitor do you have available at your workstation?"

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I would like that :P

Comment: *“Think back to the last time you updated your resumé, CV, or an online profile on a job site. What is the main reason that you did so?”* – Why is “Stack Overflow told me to update my developer story” not an option?

Comment: Have you considered doing testing with external users before going live, instead of only doing in-house testing? Every year multiple issues are reported shortly after the survey going live, it's unfortunate this mistake is made every time.

Comment: @Stijn I agree, by now there must be a fair bit of data collected that won't be correct when matched against the new options.

Comment: Why were there so many questions about advertisement? Is this whole survey thing just a cover for you to evaluate how to improve your advertising revenue? Because that's exactly how it felt after 3 pages of asking about my advertising preferences and habits...

Comment: Next year, please do some QA including non-US testers before releasing the survey. I was struggling with a lot of questions. Unfortunately, I can no longer view the survey, because I have already finished it. So I can't provide more detailed feedback :(

Comment: No opportunity to get swag by guessing coins, M&M's or whatnot? Terrible tradition-breaker :-(

Comment: @musefan I thought the Ad questions were interesting. Adblockers and peoples' motivations behind them are relevant to a much larger domain than just SO. Of course, they might benefit from the answers as well, but I didn't feel taken advantage of.

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Interesting they may be, but they have no relevance to being a developer nor career/employment, and are therefore out of place in such a survey as this. If it was a single question I could have let it go, but 3 pages is a pretty heavy focus which means you have to wonder why they are there in the first place. There are not really many logical reasons to put them in there other than what I already suggested in my previous comment. Can you offer a different reason than mine?

Comment: I wish there were more questions from [The Topic Suggestions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357936/developer-survey-2018-any-topic-suggestions) post from October. It seems like only the "basic" ones were implemented

Comment: @musefan I think I see your point. I was wondering if it was included from the angle of "These are some of the most tech savvy people in the world. I wonder what the educated elite think about this web practice."  Kind of like an expert-opinion, at least from the side of tech, if not advertising.

Comment: What does advertising have to do with developers?

Comment: The primary purpose of the survey [has always been about improving our ability to serve relevant advertising](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/12/21/stack-overflow-annual-survey/), @musefan. We've expanded it considerably over the past 7 years to try to make the results more generally useful and interesting, and last year's results seem to have been widely successful in achieving that secondary goal, but that core need remains in place - IMHO, that's a far better bargain than the sorts of intrusive analytics (with secret results) that certain other sites use for this purpose.

Comment: @Shog9: Interesting to know, thanks for the link. Though now I am left wondering if I would have took the survey if I had known that in advance... I guess we will never know, but could make for an interesting final question on the actual survey! "Would you have took the survey if you had known it was for the purpose of improvement our advertising?" (Yes / No / I did already know and I'm here now aren't I)

Comment: That'd be super meta, @musefan! Perhaps this is best seen as a reminder that stuff we've grown to take as self-evident (like the answer to those "five whys" in the post I linked) is still worth calling out for the benefit of the many folks who haven't been around for all these years. So, thanks for that - I'll try & keep it in mind next time around.

Comment: Why do you want to know my sexual preference?

Comment: So what's up regarding the survey being automatically linked to our profiles or not? See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361596/change-the-description-of-the-census-badge

Comment: You mean you're not on Stack Overflow Dating yet @TimCastelijns?

Comment: Every single link - email, SO, MSO thread - ends up with... a stupid revolving circle. (Is this a test? If so, I hope I provided enough details.) I tried Safari, Chrome, and Firefox latest version. Same issue. Yep, I use Ghostery. What am I missing? EDIT: Do I *really* need to use MSIE6? I lost **that** backup in 2006. That's my story and I'm sticking to it.

Comment: Missing Option: I use an adblocker for security.

The reason I use an adblocker has nothing to do with how I feel about ads, and 100% because ad networks are malicious code vectors.

Comment: Your list of currencies under "Which currency do you use day-to-day?" is out of order, and the identifiers are wrong. Canadian Dollars is CAD, not C$.

Comment: @Shog9 You should *always* disclose the purpose of a survey and not make assumptions about your audience.

Comment: @DenysSéguret perhaps an option like 'Not compatible with my Culture'.

Comment: Bermuda is not in the countries list. Can you add it?

Comment: Statistics 101, a 30 minute survey is similar to torture techniques for combatants. Information received is mostly unreliable.

Comment: It should be "Xcode", not "XCode" for the development environments question.

Comment: While this doesn't really apply to SO, the whole section on advertising is hopelessly skewed by leaving users unable to report what is most probably the #1 most hated thing about online advertising: it's frequently intrusive and extremely annoying. Does that mean it's not "trustworthy" or "honest about its goals"? I don't know, but if you make my speakers blare at 90dB uninvited I don't really care if I like your company or you avoid fluffy language.

Comment: Also to reiterate @JoelAnderson's point, adblockers are about security, period. There is no whitelisting or trusted sites or "oh that site's mainstream so they won't have malicious code". Companies have shown again and again they don't police their ad networks: https://twitter.com/SwiftOnSecurity/status/950088799014572034

Comment: Please add "Oracle Cloud".

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist The purpose of most advertising networks is to track you in order to put ads in front of you that are more effective at getting you to click them, and infect your computer with malware. I have yet to see an ad that says this up front.

Comment: @musefan Note that this post was posted by a marketing manager. What else you can expect from them?

Comment: "By participate we mean ask, answer, vote for, or comment on questions" .... it's kinda sad to see that you've forgotten moderators who spend all their time deleting stuff :-(

Comment: Ghostery prevented a redirect from 
stackoverflow.com to stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com, 
which is part of Qualtrics.

Comment: Gave up at the "rank these 10/11 items in order" questions: most I don't care about enough to rank, so the results would be random/meaningless. The old format, where you gave a ranking to only as many as you wanted was much better. If you must show off your "look, we can do drag-and-drop JS/CSS" skills, add an "_I don't care below this entry_" option that can be dragged to the appropriate place.

Comment: Overall I'm pretty disappointed with the survey this year in how obviously and overwhelmingly tailored toward jobs and ads it was. This was not a 'developer survey' so much as an 'ads harvesting survey'. On top of that, the quality of the survey in both questions and UX felt entirely phoned in. I feel like my membership on SO has been cheapened by this survey, and that SO is signalling it doesn't care about SO anymore beyond its ability to sell people advertisements and job listings. SO should be about questions and answers first and foremost, not jobs, not ads, not AI, *ad infinitum*.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site on the Stack Exchange network. Stack Exchange network sites are for asking questions and getting answers. I feel unfairly targeted as a site that all of these annoying projects get applied to Stack Overflow and not the network as a whole; it's like we can't have the site we want, which is an SE network site about programming, because you guys keep messing with it because it is "special". There's nothing special about it, it's just the biggest. Stop applying all your company initiatives to one site please.

Comment: @Arvo I use Ghostery on Firefox with everything blocked and didn't experience any issues.

Comment: @musefan "is this survey aimed at the unemployed" you are claiming you don't have 30 minutes of total free time spread throughout a week or two/however long this survey is open? I find that hard to believe... billions of people around the world work every day and still have time for a TV show or a book when not working.

Comment: @TylerH: Unfortunately I spend ALL of my free time writing pointless comments on SO

Comment: Like @TylerH, I’m also rather disappointed with this year’s survey. I remember that I was recommending the survey last year to coworkers since I believed that it was a really good survey that would yield really interesting results about the overall developer community. Having taken this survey, I simply could not do the same this year. Subjectively, the survey’s quality has fallen a lot, and it feels somewhat disconnected from the community. I consider this very sad as I always enjoyed the survey and was always looking forward to the results.

Comment: @musefan You should probably stop then!

Comment: Piggybacking off of @poke's response to my comments, I should clarify that I understand the goal of Stack Overflow with the survey is so that it can harvest ad-related information in a 'friendly' way. But this was facilitated in the past by presenting the survey in a way that made it seem relevant and interesting to *us*, the users. **You catch more flies with honey.** While this survey will likely yield a lot of useful data for your advertisers and paying customers, it won't yield anything of interest to us. So why should we take it/care about it?

Comment: I see WAY TOO MUCH posts and comments about typos or the way things are written in this survey, or just about the style of the buttons... Who cares ? You really want to make so many people waste time on such useless details ? Impressive...

Comment: @TylerH I think the point of the 30 minute comment is that a 30 minute survey is not a fun use of free time. TV and books are fun. I write a lot of surveys and we always aim for 2 - 15 minutes, depending on audience

Comment: too many US centered questions to feel comfortable. where should i put health insurance importance when it's 100% free, granted the moment you are born, in 99% of the countries around me?

Comment: the survey was too long and also there was too many questions about advertisement ;)

Comment: Just me that was quite pleasantly surprised to be answering a survey that actually had at least some thought put into it? I've encountered so many BAD surveys, this makes a nice change. I find the nitpicking a bit over the top to be honest, everyone should calm down.

Comment: I question whether "people who take the time to complete a 30 minute survey" is representative of the population of interest.

Comment: I took the survey yesterday. There is a question what is most important for me at a job and I should sort it. One answer is "health insurance". It's unusual (except in USA) to not have a health insurance by law. Since SO is not just available in USA, the sort order of the answers is somehow falsified.

Comment: Clearly aimed at a US audience. Advertisement questions put me off completely. Did not complete the survery.

Comment: Completely agree with many people : too many things are completely US-centric and oblivious to the rest of the world. Don't be surprised if 90% percent of answers are from the US, despite the site's traffic stats. Health insurance is free and mandatory for everyone, here. Degrees and education are handled completely differently, I don't even know what a bachelor degree is. My degree doesn't "match" any US degree.

Comment: Far too many questions (some of them borderline). Next time I may not take the survey.

Comment: Honestly... I'm just disappointed with this survey. The questions, the answers allowed, the lack of "community feel".  I don't know how else to express this without seeming like a whiner - But I'm just left disappointed.

Comment: All the advertising questions must be helping.  I've been here almost nine years, and this is the first time I've seen an invitation to participate in the survey.  In fact, I only found out about it from some of the 2017 blog posts.

Comment: There was an item about the "diversity" of the company.  It wasn't clear to me whether this meant the diversity of the employees (gender, culture, age, etc.) or the diversity of what the company does (provides many products and services in different categories).

Comment: In the what-prompted-you-to-update-your-résumé? question, there was no "Other" or "None of the above" option.

Comment: No name of "angular" in technologies i want to learn or technologies i worked.

Comment: The survey this year was seriously lacking the depth of the questions from the last year. The dragging interface would hide the true priorities I would have given to the items (some I would have given 0 all the same, neither really any more important)

Comment: Should of had a question on how satisfied with the amount of coding we were doing at our jobs. Very relevant for me.

Comment: Where do I file bug reports? Clicking Next takes me nowhere. The console says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElement' of undefined Just got a page template transaction id 13 but we are on 13. Ignoring new template.

Comment: Is it normal that I could take 2 times the survey? I got the census badge on the 8th of January and I could still take today the survey and complete it a second time

Comment: There should have been an option to skip the question. In **all** of them.

Comment: Where can I get the dataset of this year survey to download

Comment: @DeepakKumarTP do you mean 2017's data? You can get that here: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/  This year's (2018) results will be available in late May.

Comment: I didn't get any of the "Rank these in order" questions that others have mentioned. Have they been removed from the survey?

Answer (score 187):

All these rank questions don't really work. On every one there are a bunch I care about and a bunch I don't. Forcing me to give a full ranking will give you largely random data. One person's rank-2 may mean "very important" while another person's may mean "completely irrelevant".

You should have used the standard 5-point scale rating for each one. If you wanted more relative detail, then e.g. a 100-point slider (with the five labels in appropriate positions) should work.

Comment: Interesting point. I wonder if there is literature on this topic proving what you intuitively assert.

Comment: Also, I there was no option like "I don't want to answer". I guess the default order will appear in the result set most often...

Comment: @honk the numbers are invisible until you start moving around, so I guess it at least knows if you've skipped it entirely. [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361603/476716)

Comment: @OrangeDog: And what if for a user the default order is fine and the user wants it to be considered and continues without moving any item?

Comment: @honk as I say, the methodology for these questions is completely broken anyway, so it's a moot point

Comment: @OrangeDog: OK, I agree :)

Comment: I'd give this 100 upvotes. For most questions, whatever after the 6th option, for me, was "I don't care".

Comment: @BlackVegetable Yes, in fact there is. :) When I was taking survey methods we read a lot by Dillman and a couple papers that were critical of ranking based questions.

Comment: Completely agree with this. I certainly felt like I was over-inflating some of the lower choices when I truly couldn't care less about any of them. This one could have been fixed by assigning each one a score, or if you really wanted to get clever, give 100 points to distribute across the options and let the user decide how many to assign each one. Too late now I guess.

Comment: I gave up the survey at this point for the same reason OrangeDog says: there are probably two or three options I'd care enough about to rank but the rest would be random. If you must keep the drag-and-drop format (has someone found a shiny new JS library?), add a "_I don't care below this entry_" option that can be dragged to the appropriate place.

Comment: You need to vary the way of information retrieval because as much as it might be confusing a sequence of 30 agree/disagree batteries might scare away more people (and you run into more inter-item correlations like tendencies to the middle, left or right - you have to admit that you had to think a bit for this one  - and that's what it's for and why it's necessary. An "I don't know" and "I don't want to answer option has to be added to every question in professional survey. This requirement is unrelated to the form of the item.

Comment: I left that window with default ranking. I can't spend 10 min to figure out how to arrange 10 items which may or may not be related to me

Comment: Those were most annoying for me too, but all noise can (and should) be eliminated by statistical analysis. You can tell, with a large enough sample, if there is or there isn't a definitive tendency towards something, and of course responses won't be 100% correct, but again a large sample should be consistent enough (if you feel two are equal, you'll put them 1 after 2, and somebody else 2 after 1). Also, I think it's sane to assume default order is randomized so to prevent any bias (actually, it'd be pretty insane not to randomize default order).

Comment: These rankings made me upset too. 1/ Weird default look w/o visible weights of individual answers; 2/ pain to fill - no sane way to input these using a keyboard 3/ missing option to throw an answer out from the ranking

Answer (score 184):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) We added both Oracle & sqlite to the question.

Please add Oracle to the list of "databases you have worked with in the last year".

Oracle is far more prevalently used than most of the databases listed.

---

As per [@Sklivvz](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7028/sklivvz)'s comment, please add sqlite too.

Comment: Also: sqlite is very used in desktop apps

Comment: You can write your option

Comment: @Masiama But that could be said of all options. Why not just have an entry field? No. Oracle is **very** widely used, especially in older organizations, where it is possibly the most commonly used database. Either remove 80% of the options, or add in Oracle... nothing else makes sense.

Comment: I think the reason is they didn't want an equivalent of "Tick here if you've ever been a member of a terrorist organisation." What if you select it by accident - who knows what'd happen?

Comment: Please also add "Oracle Cloud".

Comment: @Bruno "Oracle" is close enough. There's no value is breaking down flavours. In case you live in an Oracle induced superiority bubble, most databases offer cloud, clustered, distributed and similar flavours.

Comment: The proper name to be added to the database section is Oracle Database. However, there was a section that included AWS and Azure (I think) but omitted Oracle Cloud.

Comment: (full disclosure, I work for Oracle)

The fact that you managed to build an IT survey without managing to mention Oracle even once suggests more than just accidental omission but malicious bias.  That's pretty poor form for StackOverflow.

Comment: Most of the internetz eg [this site](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3019332/database/oracle-remains-most-popular-database-but-mongodb-continues-to-rise.html) or [this site](https://db-engines.com/en/ranking) says that Oracle is #1 used in the world. WTF did stack overflow not include it?

Comment: Makes no sense why Oracle was omitted. https://twitter.com/jeffreykemp/status/950533565241896960

Comment: @JumpingJezza "#1 used in the world" depends on how you measure it. I guarantee that there are more *instances* of mysql than oracle (due to oracle's draconian per-CPU fee structure). Google for example extensively uses the [LAMP stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) and they run gazzilions of servers.

Comment: @Bohemian, "Oracle" is a company. "Oracle Database" is a technology, and so is "Oracle Cloud". That's why you see in the list "AWS", "Azure", "Amazon Echo", "Firebase", "Google Cloud", "Windows Desktop"... And not just "Amazon", or "Microsoft", or "Google".

So yes, "Oracle Cloud" and "Oracle Database" should have been included (each into its related section).

Comment: SQLite is also used by Android apps for default database

Comment: @dev.mi Except it calls into play the competence of the people that made the survey when they miss obvious things like Oracle. If you want accurate survey data you want to minimize respondent burden as much as possible.

Comment: So as of this morning, Oracle is ON THE SURVEY. There was an error on our part and we apologize. It was absolutely not purposeful or malicious, especially since Oracle is a client of ours. I am going to be handling the analysis of this question carefully (looking at the responses from the 1st day separately from the rest) to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: @Julia Rather than let errors like this through to production, next time why not have the community review such lists *before* releasing survey? There is an army of SO users who would donate their time to review questions - you should use this resource.

Comment: This is apparently news worthy.  See https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/01/09/oracle_missing_from_stack_overflow_database_survey/

Comment: @Bohemian Pretesting of a survey instrument should always take place before it is sent, see ["6 Ways to Pretest Your Survey Before You Send It"](https://www.qualtrics.com/blog/6-ways-to-pretest-your-survey-before-you-send-it/)

Comment: Now Oracle is there in survey

Comment: So... If I use Oracle, but this option was NOT in the survey when I took it - and potentially those who up-voted this answer - does this not skew the results moving forward...?

Comment: @Matt people would entered "Oracle" before it was an option will be counted the same as people who selected the "Oracle" option after it was available. This kind of "data cleaning" is what data analysts routinely do.

Comment: @Bohemian, sure! but misspellings, and people who did not add the option due to it not being there could still skew things (granted, the former can be somewhat cleaned up still)

Comment: @Matt they will manually look at all the spelling variations of what was entered and make a human decision on what constitutes as "Oracle". There will of course be people who (in frustration) didn't bother to enter text and just moved on. C'est la vie. Data science may be able to lift the Oracle number to offset this effect if the there's an acceptable way of doing this (maybe there's a typical "didn't bother" rate that can be applied).

Comment: @Bohemian First off. No. People would not have entered "Oracle" if it wasn't present on the survey instrument. It has to do with respondent burden and the error rate of the survey instrument. Second, no, there is no scientifically acceptable way to extrapolate how many people have entered "Oracle" if it was an option. If you try and use the differences between before and after the field was present you are just going to increase the error rate of the survey. Third, in survey methods they teach you a *a lot* about how to construct a scientifically valid survey. The survey that was ...

Comment: ... administered *is not scientifically valid!* So many basic methodological processes were broken that we can use this survey as a case study for what not to do. Pragmatically Stack Exchange should really think about hiring (full time or a consultant) a survey methodologist if this is intended to be a proper scientific survey and service to the community. Data science techniques cannot and should not be used to address the short comings in how the survey was designed and administered.

Comment: @rjzii I get what you are saying, but we aren't using this survey for medical research. An estimated/projected number for Oracle is good enough for a survey that is only done for interest's sake.

Comment: @Bohemian The problem is that the the results get picked up by the broader community and potentially by the lay media as well. Stack Exchange presents the findings in an authoritative way (see., https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017) and exposes the data set to allow other people to try and draw conclusions from it. If you are going to try and do something in an authoritative way (i.e., have data scientists analyze the data and present findings on it) it behooves you do make sure that what you are doing can stand up to the scrutiny of other scientists.

Comment: With some students, the answer "I'm a student who is learning to code" doesn't necessarily make sense.  For example, if I'm a senior/fourth-year undergrad, I'm probably not "learning to code," but I am still learning things about computer science in general.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 140):

#### On the assumption of the American job market:

I'm currently a Student in Germany. I already have completed a vocational education and worked for a bit before hitting University.

The following items in the "benefits package" are **mandatory** in Germany:

- Parental Leave
- Health insurance
- Equipment Allowance, given a medical need for it
- Retirement savings matching (for the enforced minimum retirement savings)

It's nearly impossible to rank benefits that are mandated by law... 
Results from Germany (and quite probably a lot of European countries) will accordingly be skewed.

If you have a way to fix the question, that's just fine as well.

#### Ambiguous Framework name(s?):

In the section "frameworks, libraries and tools have you done extensive development work in [..]", I assume that "Spark" refers to "Apache Spark" and not "Spark-Java", the first being a big-data framework and the latter being a simple REST-Server framework

Overall I like that there's more options to amend missing answer options.

Comment: Given the benefits, you can still rank them by personal preference even if they're mandatory.

Comment: They're still either important to you or not, aren't they?

Comment: What about if for example you do not have children, so you put "Parental Leave" as least important as it's "not applicable". Surely that would skew results?

Comment: RE: the frameworks; I find the list to be strangely small anyway. I guess it is based on trending tags, but what is hoped to be learned from the question I do not know...

Comment: @ivarni try ranking whats more important: grocery stores or gas stations. Sure they are important, but I am not able to usefully prioritize things that are 'just there' since I before I could think

Comment: @Vogel612 Imagine how much you'd miss those and try, I had no problems ranking them by how important they are for me and Norway has them as mandatory as well.

Comment: For the record I'd rank grocery stores higher than gas stations because I'd miss them more if they were gone.

Comment: @ivarni You cannot rank them according to how it would be without them though since the perception is very different. To me, health insurance is a guaranteed thing. I actually have a hard time imagining being without it, and I would probably never take a job without having health insurance (assuming I take work outside of Germany). So I would personally rank this #1 but this is mostly because I am used to this as being a default and because being in a situation without it is unthinkable to me. But that thinking does not apply to other countries where health insurance is not a default.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Germany, but do some companies go above and beyond the minimum needed by law? If so, the question still makes sense. If going above and beyond the law is important to you, then it should be ranked higher. If you're OK with the minimum required, then it would be ranked lower.

Comment: s/Germany/EU -- also to the point: if they are required by law they are not benefits. Your right to strike is protected by law, it's not a benefit.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts here. International differences in workplace culture are something we always try to think through when writing survey questions for our worldwide audience of developers. Our goal is to not to have many questions that only get shown to developers in certain countries, so we try to write these to apply broadly but in ways that hopefully most/many can interpret, as some of these other commenters did.

Comment: You have a good point. I'm also EU and took the survey just now. Almost without thinking I've put the "guaranteed by law" items at the end of my priorities. It's not that they are not important, it's just that they are, well... guaranteed. I do feel, by intuition, and by quite recent experience there will be some bias.

Comment: I'm not sure how it is in Germany, but over here a company can go above and beyond the minimum with a private health insurance in addition to the ubiquitous public health care and they can pay more than the required amount for retirement savings. I've no idea about parental leave but I suppose noone can *stop* anyone from giving an employee an extra paid month of.

Comment: Some benefits are mandatory even in the US. But I agree--I put the ones that were most common in the US (salary & health care) at the top, even though in practice I might be better incentivized by a nice stock options package with a merely average health plan. The question could definitely be clarified, since "this is important to me"  might mean "I don't actually care how *nice* my healthcare package is so long as I have *some* healthcare package", but it could also mean "I need a really nice health care package".

Comment: @ThomasOwens Not sure how it is in Germany, but I assume it is the same in the Netherlands. In the Netherlands the goverment makes it mandatory, companies are usually not involved. Sometimes companies offer a collective insurance, which is more like a deal they can make to reduce costs a bit if enough people agree to switch the insurance provider.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Some things may not change. But for other things, like parental leave, if the minimum is 6 months, there's nothing stopping a company from offering 9 or 12 months or some other perks related to parental leave (the minimum time off plus additional time of flex work or something). If you were planning on having a child, a company that is extremely flexible with parental leave could be a game changing decision. But again - I don't know how it works in Europe. Maybe very few if any companies offer more than the minimum.

Comment: Australia also has a minimum percentage of the salary that all (but the smallest) employers must contribute to a retirement fund.

Comment: Presumably the point of the question is to help employers target their benefits packages. Therefore, answers to the question will not be very useful to employers in those regions where the options are automatic and required; so I'd put those options at the bottom of the list.

Comment: I personally imagined they weren't mandatory and ranked which I'd choose if I could only have one of them first.

Comment: Given the ambiguity the question results in, I suggest you only publish results from participants in countries where all these items are negotiable. The rest of the answers to this question should be discarded because they are not a reliable measure of the question.

Comment: This annoyed me too, especially since I have pointed out the same issue previously, on earlier surveys. In the majority of the counties in the western world, "health insurance" etc are covered by the government, not by private companies. USA stands out as an exception here, lagging behind the rest of the western world by 50 years or so.

Comment: `.Net Framework Core` was ambiguous too. I am currently making only desktop application (winforms, wpf). Is it "modern frameworks only" question? Then maybe it is worth stating that explicitly in the question?

Comment: @Lundin you are politicizing the issue. This is a data analysis problem.

Comment: @armatita The root of all problems in these surveys have always been "lets assume that every company everywhere in the world works just like the SO office in USA".

Comment: @Lundin I don't know if that is true. But even if it was, making nation wide comparisons is bound to be contentious and unfair. SO does what SO decides to do. What does the remaining US, EU, or anyone else have to do with it? I'm don't mean to be judgmental towards your approach but there are better ways to adresse these issues that benefit everyone, no matter their flag of preference.

Comment: Health insurance is a must for me so it should be top priority? But as said it is enforced by law in most first world countrys. So i get extra stuff, more than required by law. Which is not that important to me, so I should rank it low? You see @ThomasOwens this makes not much sense in the end

Comment: It is a pity that educated folks mistake the term "america" to refer to a country whereas it is clearly defined as referring to a "continent".  Let's refer to a building to designate a city then.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo It's very simple. Would having health insurance that goes above and beyond the minimum standards be critical in making a decision about taking a job? If so, rank it higher. If you're OK with the minimum allowed coverage, rank it toward the bottom.

Comment: @ThomasOwens this makes the data useless, because the ranking would be foremost dependend on the enforced law in the country. I would rank it in place 1 living in the USA but in on of the last place here because the care enforced by law is really good. A Healthcare at all or a superior healtcare is not the same to rank, it is like to say if it is important to get a pc for work vs get a gaming rig for work...

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I would agree that it's OK to question the validity of the question, especially if you don't tie it to location. However, that's a different proposition than saying that the question is unclear or unanswerable just because you have guarantees of minimum standards that others may not have.

Comment: @ThomasOwens fair point, I agree with you on that! Thank you for clarifying. However the fact, that a lot of countrys have care enforced by law makes this question useless. And pointing out useless stuff is in my opinion the sense of this topic. So you are completly right, but here it doesn't matter if it is unanwserable or useless (again my opinion). But I can tell you I already did what you suggested before we had this discussion.

Comment: @ThomasOwens maybe you don't understand ( not being pedant) that the countries that enforce it by law mostly if not all already provide full coverage. in my country there is nothing beyond that, except maybe "quicker response times" when you have a nonimportant illness and you need quick medication, else, you're all covered. got cancer? treated. got back pain? treated. cut a leg? treated. have insomnia? treated. private & public  severe operations are performed on the public centers, you get full treatment, medicines are either free or almost free. there's no way to rank that comparatively.

Comment: As I have universal health care provided by the state, company health insurance is largely irrelevant to me. If I lived somewhere else then things would be completely different.

Comment: The survey also asks what country you live in. So don't worry about the potential biases introduced by that; those can easily be accounted for via a by-country breakdown when analysing the results.

Comment: @Ajedi32 no they can't, because the controlling for country can not deal with different interpretations of how to handle "benefits" that are mandated by law. The idea is nice, but it's simply not correct

Comment: @Vogel612 Sure it can. For example, you could just remove "required by law" benefits from consideration entirely in those countries, and only consider the benefits that are not required.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Hi, social scientist here. No, the interpenetration doesn't work that way.

Comment: @rjzii Could you elaborate on that? The importance of each entry in the list is relative, so removing the mandatory benefits shouldn't affect the results. Unless you're saying people would order non-mandatory benefits differently relative to each other based on the presence or absence of mandatory benefits in the list? (Which seems completely illogical to me, but maybe that's just because I'm more experienced dealing with computers than people.)

Comment: @Ajedi32 You are correct that people would order the benefits differently. Remember that in the EU people are more likely to move between countries. So just because someone says they are currently in DE doesn't mean they weren't originally raised in the UK or even the US for that matter. The cultural group that you were raised in is going to bias the responses and can affect the interpretation if you aren't aware of that potential basis. So someone from the US currently in DE might highly value the (mandatory) health insurance. ...

Comment: ... In contrast, someone from the DE in the US may rank their insurance very low since they expect employers to provide it by default. Developing and interpreting international surveys is really hard because of situations like this. I can't recall if it was on the survey, but if I were designing one I'd mostly include a control question along the lines of "Do you work in the country you were born?" so I could take that into account in the analysis. A lot of survey design is focused on anticipating independent and dependent variables and situations like this that can skew the results.

Answer (score 114):

The styling of the radio buttons is needlessly unconventional, and it's confusing:

[image]

It's a pretty universal convention that a radio button is marked as selected by putting a dot inside it. This styling makes it look like the radio button is merely *focused*, rather than selected. I actually aborted and restarted the survey after rapidly clicking through the first page because I thought I hadn't entered an answer on the last question.

Can we have a dot? There was no reason to mess with this.

Comment: Yes, the "focussed and checked" style confused me too.

Comment: Adding to the fire is the fact the lit up effect dies down upon clicking another button

Comment: From a developer point-of-view: The background of the focus style is overriding the background of the selected style. That’s why the filling feels so terrible. If you remove the background from the focus, everything makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Re: "There was no reason to mess with this." I think it's clear there is always a reason to mess with older paradigms, which is: there's something newer. Sometimes the newer thing is better from a functional standpoint, other times it is not. Some organizations may feel like they have to use the newest thing, for no other reason than to avoid *looking* out of date.

Answer (score 102):

Not trying to be rude here, but I think answering 'I identify as an autistic person' is too much over the top. This actually implies people choose to be autistic, or just identify as those. Autism and or a disorder in the related spectrum is a mental condition, not a social construct.

Autism Speaks website:

> Autism, or autism spectrum disorder, refers to a range of conditions characterized by challenges with social skills, repetitive behaviors, speech and nonverbal communication, as well as by unique strengths and differences. We now know that there is not one autism but many types, caused by different combinations of genetic and environmental influences.

You might assume you have some sort of, or symptoms implying autism, but **identifying** sounds just plain wrong. I'd like to suggest one of the following:

- I’ve been diagnosed with a disorder in the autism spectrum
- I believe to have a disorder or some symptoms of a disorder in the autism spectrum

Not forfeiting the rest of the options.

Comment: I found that option quite odd. I thought it was a diagnosed disorder, not some trendy thing to "identify" as.

Comment: Yeah, "I am autistic", or perhaps "I have autism", to fit with the "I have..." format of the other answers, would flow much more naturally. The attempt at political correctness here - which, as you say, carries with it the implication that what is in fact a very real (and sometimes life-ruining) mental disorder is instead some kind of subjective personal label - ends up being, as it often does, significantly more distasteful than plain English would have been.

Comment: "I'm on the autism spectrum" might be the best choice.

Comment: I would propose either ‘I’ve been diagnosed with a disorder in the autism spectrum’ and ‘I believe to have a disorder or some symptoms of a disorder in the autism spectrum’

Comment: Another question about gender had 5 choices. The survey is suffering heavily from "moral panic", trying to be politically correct to the point of silliness. That's what we see in this question too.

Comment: Alas, it's the decade of diversity -- so you can identify as whatever you wish, disregarding any reality or biology-based criteria.

Comment: @Lundin I disagree that the two are equivalent. The non-binary gender options - unlike this weird wording - actually allow the survey to gather information that it otherwise wouldn't. If I remember correctly, looking at the results last year I found that among survey respondents there was 1 male-to-female trans person per 10 non-trans females, compared to a ratio of maybe around 1 to 200 in the general population (based on Googling for US stats). That result, IMO, is interesting in its own right and a useful piece of evidence in the ongoing debate over why more women don't become programmers.

Comment: @MarkAmery That may be because the survey of the general population was made in scientific ways, while the SO survey is more of "lets ask some fun questions to people who were not randomly chosen at all".

Comment: @Lundin I'd be more concerned about [reptilian Muslim climatologists from Mars](http://slatestarcodex.com/2013/04/12/noisy-poll-results-and-reptilian-muslim-climatologists-from-mars/) sabotaging the data. If the explanation is selection bias, as you say, then that's *still* an interesting result in its own right, it's just that the explanation is nothing to do with programming and is instead *"transsexuals innately drawn to surveys: compulsively fill them in at rate 20x the rest of the population!"*. I kinda doubt it, though.

Comment: @MarkAmery Rather it would be something like that users of SO are more likely to belong to a generation where you would openly admit being transsexual. Or much more likely: there isn't enough survey participants to draw any form of conclusions from the survey what-so-ever. One perfect example is Stack Overflow Trends, where some would-be scientist made the conclusion that certain technologies were becoming less popular just because the _percentage_ of questions on SO of those technologies had been in decline. Even though the _amount_ of questions had actually increased. Dumb things like that.

Comment: @JoeFriend If it's a spectrum I'm guessing we are all "on" it. Some of us closer to 1, most of us closer to 0.

Comment: @Lundin Indeed, just because of that I was very tempted to write "I identify as a red fox" instead of choosing male/female/etc..

Comment: @BartoszKP My understanding is that people who don't have any degree of the disorder aren't on the [autism spectrum](https://visual.ly/community/infographic/health/autism-spectrum-disorder)

Comment: @JoeFriend Interesting, thanks for the link. The term is thus a bit misleading, but of course you're right :)

Comment: I came here just to point this exact thing out if no-one had already

Comment: Good answer but Autism Speaks is an autism hate group

Comment: I have seen the term "identify with autism" before, but it's not a good term. Either you believe you have an autism spectrum disorder, have been diagnosed somewhere on the spectrum, or you haven't. I'd say adding both the options is the best way to go, as there's still a difference between believing you have an autism spectrum disorder vs being formally diagnosed with it

Comment: @Izkata Me too (slightly different species though :D). I honestly think there should be a question related to that to avoid just that (since it isn't related to gender, but it's still a topic in general identity). Just a text-based one where it's possible to elaborate on identity matters could be enough (and also deals with whatever else isn't listed)

Comment: Yeah, the other "identify" questions were like sure okay, but come on, identify as autistic?

Answer (score 89):

Some of the same problems that have plagued old surveys still exist.

---

> Approximately how many people are employed by the company or organization you work for?

My office is about 70. My subsidiary is about 400 or so. My parent company is 50,000. How do I answer? Personally, I answered with the 10,000+ answer, since my paycheck has the parent company's name on it.

I'm also surprised that there's no question about development team size. Although the parent company is 50,000 strong, the development organization is much, much smaller. Even if you consider just my local office (which is a development hub), only about 50% of the office is development.

---

> Which of the following methodologies do you have experience working in?

One of the options is "Formal standard such as ISO 9001 or IEEE 12207 (aka "waterfall" methodologies)". As someone who has worked in aerospace (AS 9100, which is an industry-specific variant of ISO 9001) and pharmaceutical software (based in ISO 9001), I can tell you with absolute certainty that you can deploy  the agile methods and still be compliant with ISO 9001 (and likely most, if not all, of the industry specific variants, like AS 9100).

Some of the other options also don't make much sense. Agile and Scrum are both options? Scrum is an implementation of the agile methods (along with Extreme Programming and a number of others). Pair programming is a technique, not a method.

---

> Do you report or otherwise call out the unethical code in question?

The answers to this question are incomplete.

If one were to refer to the [Software Engineering Code of Ethics and Professional Practice](https://ethics.acm.org/code-of-ethics/software-engineering-code/), the first priority of software engineers (people "those who contribute by direct participation or by teaching, to the analysis, specification, design, development, certification, maintenance and testing of software systems") is to the general public. However, one also has obligations to the client and the employer. The first step would be to report it internally, in order to avoid public disclosure of confidential information (unless there was an immediate danger to the general public). Then, escalating the disclosure as appropriate, perhaps even to the general public - depending on the situation, it may be ethical to disclose confidential information for the greater good of society.

These questions on ethics are not really nuanced enough to get into any kind of meaningful discussion. I answered "Yes, but only within the company" since it's the correct first step based on a number of ethical codes written for computing professionals (including the one I linked to). But it doesn't have to be the last step, and this question doesn't lead to that.

---

The fact that the survey still targets "people who write code" leaves a lot to be desired. That's the primary audience of Stack Overflow. But there are plenty of non-programmers involved in developing software. I would like to see this improved in the future with surveys that are inclusive of people who are involved in analysis and specification (product managers, business analysts), architecture (architects), testing (manual testers, automated testers), management (development leads, development managers), and process improvement (Scrum Master, agile coach).

I don't know what the inclusion of these other types of roles would look like, but this survey is advertised on the entire network via the blog post. It would be nice to see questions geared toward the software developers that participate on Software Engineering, Software Quality Assurance, Project Management, and maybe a few other sites because those areas are their expertise would be very nice.

Comment: In addition, ISO 9001 is hardly "formal" as quality management standards go. It's a silly little document and can't be used for software quality by itself. If someone says "our organization writes software according to ISO 9001", then you know for certain they haven't got a clue about what they are doing.

Comment: @Lundin It's formal in the sense that it's a recognized standard with audits and a database of parties that are certified. You're right that it doesn't assure product quality - you can make garbage products with well-defined and improved processes. But it's totally possible to build a software product using a process that is compliant with ISO 9001 - I've written the necessary documentation to bring an agile process through the audit process.

Comment: ISO 9001 is some 30 pages of very vague text. You can make anything compliant to very vague text. I could easily ISO certificate my cat. Anyway, my point here is that ISO 9001 simply does not give the tools needed to define a software design process or improve its quality. It is the very same thing as putting up a sign of the door to your office saying "do not write bugs".

Comment: I would totally buy a t-shirt with "I just ISO certified my cat." printed on it.

Comment: I felt the same way about the ethical questions. All of the answers seemed somewhat valid, just at different steps in the process. I put the same answer as you for the same reasoning, though I hadn't actually heard of that source you provided. It just seemed like common sense.

Answer (score 70):

The census badge description says "you have given your profile URL" but, in reality the current profile *takes it without asking* by passing the survey answer id to my current page (and thus, implicitly knowing who I am by sending me to a registered only page on the site).

It's not *nice* to do this without warning and it's actually a (well intentioned) *lie* to claim it's otherwise in the description. Please at least fix.

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361596/change-the-description-of-the-census-badge), although the post doesn't mention the implications of that.

Comment: I took the survey when I wasn't logged in to SO, so no badge for me... unless I take it again...

Comment: I took what I thought was an anonymous survey, and only at the end realized that everything I put is going to be forever linked irrevocably to my SO profile.

Comment: I could care less about my SO profile being linked to this survey, so I was infinitesimally peeved that after inputting the email address associated with my profile (after taking the survey otherwise anonymously and not signed in via my employer's machine), that I didn't have a badge of completion waiting for me when I signed in.

Answer (score 66):

There are *design* problems with survey (don't remember how it was last year).

Namely I am not obliged to select anything, but if I select and then change my 
mind - there is no option to "unselect".

E.g. a question regarding when did I update my CV last time. Sorry, I don't even have one, so I didn't tick anything, but if I would tick one of *radio buttons* I'd be unable to remove it.

While some other questions have 1 or 2 options to *pass*: "I prefer not to answer" or custom reason (possibly blank).

P.S.: and there is no funny part this year =(

Comment: I almost fell into this one as well; I don't have a CV, and my resume is unchanged from when I first wrote it (haven't had a need so far).  No answers fit, and it would be even worse for a student who has yet to even write a resume.

Answer (score 65):

Not a fan of the "rank these statements" type questions. I choose to participate in a survey in order to quickly give honest feedback for research purposes, but these felt more like an exercise and I genuinely dreaded them when they popped up.

Say I genuinely don't care about 3 of the options, I can't give them an equal ranking even though I *equally* don't care about them. So now I feel like I'm implying that I partially care about a couple of those options.

Similarly, I may have a couple of options that are of equal significance to me - I have no way to display that.

Going forward, I think phrasing the question in the way of "which of the following *x* do you find important enough to impact your decision on *y* ?" and a list of check-boxes will suffice, and actually provide better data. You could then follow up with an optional "which of these would you consider the most/least influential" (you get the idea...)

---

**TL;DR**

My brain is taxed enough trying to support a legacy WebClass application and the primal needs of my offspring. Now you want me to prioritise options on a made up job from a recruiter I'll never talk to? Urgh...

Comment: Totally agree. I gave up at the "rank these 10/11 things" questions. I'm even more agnostic than you: there's probably only two or three I'd care enough about to rank at all.

Comment: Already discussed in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361614/1797006

Comment: @KarlRichter yes but I wanted to give my alternative for the question layout **with** the context behind it. So I posted an answer.

Comment: At the very least, there should be an option not to answer (e.g. a checkbox that says "I prefer not to answer" or something along the lines of that). Though having the option to rank multiple on the same rank (and the ability to say a specific option isn't important at all/not applicable/whatever else would also be great to have)

Answer (score 49):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) We added both Taiwan and "Other Country (Not Listed Above)" to the survey.

I can't even start the survey because my country of residence - Taiwan - is not present in the list. It's not there under any of the common names either (R.O.C., or the silly Chinese Taipei).

Please don't exclude a nation of over 20 million people from your survey.

Comment: This year, we used a standardized list of countries from our survey tool, Qualtrics. I know that there are some countries with complex identities. :/

Comment: I would at least expect the undignified "Taiwan, province of China" then, but even that's missing. I also noticed Hong Kong (SAR) is included but Macau (SAR) is not.

Comment: Also Bermuda...we may not have 20 million residents, but it sucks to not be able to continue with a Survey when it asks for geographical information based on the option I had to choose (UK)

Comment: I face same problem on 2013. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158543/where-is-my-country-in-annual-user-survey-2013

Comment: Taiwan is now on the list of countries!  We apologize for our error in not including this from the beginning. Also, there is now an option of "Other Country (Not Listed Above)" to be able to include lots of small countries.

Comment: P.R. China will soon file a complaint that Taiwan shouldn't be a *country* :)

Answer (score 45):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) We added "None of the above" to the questions about disability.

Add "Not disabled" to the list of disability options.

This allows the important distinction between a person that has a disability but selects "Prefer not to answer" and someone who doesn't have a disability who wants to answer such.

Currently, not answering at all and "prefer not to answer" don't allow collection of data that someone is definitely not disabled.

Same goes for the "behavioural problems" question.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up; we have edited these questions to clarify them and will be analyzing the data so that leaving it blank is equivalent to "Not disabled" and "Prefer not to answer". This question will be kept private (not part of the public data release) and any data analysis will only use positive responses, i.e. respondents who identified with a difference/disability.

Comment: @JuliaSilge Wouldn't that approach introduce a lot of error into the analysis?

Comment: With this kind of survey where people are very free to leave answers blank, we don't expect to be able to make strong statements about what proportion of developers have differences/disabilities. Instead, what is more possible is to say something like "The most common disability reported is X. It is Y times as common as Z. People were A times more likely to report mental differences/disabilities than physical." Things like that.

Comment: @JuliaSilge To be fair, any survey that is subjected to IRB allows for non-response to questions and it's just something that we have to deal with in the design and analysis. Basing the analysis on just the positive responses makes sense, but I do question if those questions should have even been included.

Comment: *“The most common disability reported is X”* – Weren’t the answers far too unspecific for that purpose?

Answer (score 37):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

It says "10 is least important". Then what is 11?

[image: bug]

Comment: *These go to 11*

Comment: @ivarni But why not just make 10 less important?

Comment: Hah! Let's pretend that was a subtle Spinal Tap reference and not a mistake. :)

Comment: That's so minor. I didn't even noticed. The *hint* part of such questions was clearly copy/pasted. How would this create a problem to anyone?

Comment: Can I ask a practical question at this point? Are we gonna do Stonehenge tomorrow night?

Comment: @RandyLevy By answering this question, you've already done a Stonehenge :)

Comment: Its 1 extra unimportant

Answer (score 37):

I saw Shog9's comment that the intent of this survey is primarily to acquire marketing data; however, from a methodological standpoint this survey is very flawed if you want to comment on developers as a broader population. Since the survey is already in progress *you should not change it!* However, a couple suggestions for next year:

1. Disclose in the introduction that the intent of the survey is to gather data for marketing purposes.
2. Hopefully you did this, but given some of the feedback on Meta it is possible you didn't, do a small test to make sure the questions and answers make sense. Going through the survey there were a couple places where the answers "nudged" the respondent a certain way, that is bad.
3. Make sure questions are clear to minimize respondent burden, it should be clear in the question how someone should answer if they have "*x*.5 years of experience" ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361632/1185)).
4. Similarly, define what you mean by terms like "contribute" - is submitting a bug report to an open source project a contribution, testing, documentation, etc?
5. Don't repeat questions. I seem to recall that I was asked about my education at least twice for basic information and demographic information.
6. Make better use of your platform. For example, the question about programming languages could have allowed for free-text that was validated against a database. A measure of niche languages that are used could have been done with that approach and it would prevent respondent fatigue or misentry if someone clicks "Rush" instead of "Ruby."
7. Your use of a convenience sample means you **cannot** say this is
   "the largest and most comprehensive survey of software developers
   (and anyone else who codes!) on Earth." [IRB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_review_board) would have my head
   for making a claim like that.

Comment: I wasn't asked twice about education, but I was asked once about my education, and then once about my parents'. Perhaps this is what you're (mis-)remembering in point 5?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Possibly. Generally I don't take notes when doing survey's unless people are explicitly asking for feedback on the design.

Comment: I agree with the first sentence about making it clear this helps marketing... and then there was all that other stuff which I kind of disagreed with but didn't take notes on.

Answer (score 36):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) We added "None of the above" to the questions about disability.

Can we fix these questions?

> Which of the following describe you, if any? This information will be kept private. If you prefer not to answer, you may leave this question blank.

They have a "I prefer not to answer" answer.

Having both could skew results.

Comment: Hey! Person who wrote the survey, here. We decided to have both here so that it'd be abundantly clear that the question is optional, and to make people as comfortable as possible with possibly sensitive questions. They won't be treated any differently in the data.

Comment: @KristinaLustig i felt that none applied to me which is different than "I prefer not to answer"

Comment: Totally - we're going to add in a "none of the above" option. It's a good point that someone else made in a different thread. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 31):

At the question: **Think back to the last time you updated your resumé, CV, or an online profile on a job site. What is the main reason that you did so?**

The question assumes everybody updates it CV because they need a (different) job. My employer wants me to update my CV regularly because I'm a consultant and when going on a new assignment the customer could ask for it.
None of the options matched this IMO.

At the question: **What is your current gross salary (before taxes and deductions), in {currency}**
I assume the salary question, asks for the yearly gross? Not really clear because it also says "If you are paid hourly, please estimate an equivalent weekly, monthly, or yearly salary. "

At the question: **Which of the following tools do you use to communicate, coordinate, or share knowledge with your coworkers? Please select all that apply.**
Where is TFS? :( I mean, Trello is in there, shouldn't TFS be in there as well?

At the question: **What do you do for childcare or dependent care while you are working?**
Uhm... nothing? My children do not need to go to childcare, I never said they go there.

Please stop assuming so much in the survey, I skipped the survey last year because I got so irritated of all the assumption. I understand that is my problem, but still...

Comment: Apparently "email" is a thing of the past for communicating with coworkers.

Comment: As far as the childcare question, perhaps your spouse takes care of your children? Or they go to school? People have kids and also work do typically have to figure out something to do with them during work hours. :)

Comment: @cpburnz Email is soooo 2017!

Comment: The update CV also missed the simple option "I was up for a new challenge". The options provided were (all?) negative ones.

Comment: @JanDoggen I noticed that too, I interpreted most to be pretty similar. Someone could also update his CV, because he/she likes to keep stuff like that updated... There are a lot of reasons, so an options 'Something different [Textbox]' might have been better.

Comment: What about using phones? What about not speaking to coworkers at all since you are doing a one man company?

Comment: See Also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361616

Comment: @AshleyMedway I know, I already placed the link to this answer in the comments there.

Comment: @cpburnz We use email for notifications, not communication (which I read two-way, not a one-way broadcast).  So, yeah - thing of the past over here.

Answer (score 30):

> What ergonomic furniture or devices do you use on a regular basis? Please select all that apply.

Please add an option of "No use of ergonomic furniture". In that case how can one tell if no answer means no use or skipped question? I had to skip while I do not use any ergonomic furniture.

---

> Please rank the following aspects of a job's benefits package from most to least important to you

The options of "Parental leave" and "Childcare benefit" do not apply to me - giving them any mark will influence the overall analyzing of these options (assuming I'm not the only one answering this question and am not a parent). I think there should be a question before that asking if I'm a parent or not any according to that include the options.

Maybe a better way to answer is by ranking only those that are important to me (and my order) and the rest as "not ranked" - if they do not apply to me (or any other reason such as mentioned by @Vogel612 - in Israel too some are mandatory and it makes little sense to rank them..)

---

> What is your current gross salary (before taxes and deductions), in **Some other currency**:?

My salary is in a currency not in the list. It took me a long time to realize that the "Some other currency" is actually the option I selected before but not the text I entered.

I think it is best to place the text written before, or change the question before to be a drop-down with all the currencies

---

One minor improvement - after selecting an option/filling in text, I think pressing enter should proceed to the next question.

Comment: I, too, eschew the use of ergonomic furniture, much preferring the superior Reganomic designs that allow spilled drinks to trickle down to the base. No option for that either though.

Comment: @Shog9 - sorry... but don't really get your point. The question is about use of ergonomics, at least it should have the option of no ergonomic stuff are used. About any specific type - I guess having a few common ones as options make sense and then if you really want the one that allows you to spill drinks then to have an option of "other" and specify... The whole reason I pointed it out is that they can't tell if I just skipped the question or actually don't use any.

Comment: Sorry @Gilad - I was making light of the fact that we're still using the term "ergonomic" in 2018 (chances are, you *are* using an ergonomic device of some sort unless all of your equipment is 30+ years old; it means "designed for human use" and has thus become a trite marketing term like "fresh" or "natural" - taken literally, it has only slightly more appeal than buying a can of soda emblazoned with "NO RAT POISON". Of course, the intended meaning was to differentiate new products from older ones that were often *not* designed for the wide variety of shapes and limitations in humans.)

Comment: No kids here, either, but "parental leave" and "childcare benefits" are important to me because of what they say about the company culture.

Comment: @Shog9 "Of course, the intended meaning was to differentiate new products from older ones" - If that was the intended meaning, then that's what it should ask.  All my furniture and devices are less than 5 years old,  none of it labeled "ergonomic".

Comment: The intended meaning of the *term*, @Izkata, when used in marketing. As in "ergonomic keyboard". Contrast with how the term is used by, say, OSHA, where it involves structuring both task and workplace to avoid causing injury to employees (trivia: software shops are exempt from those regulations). The point of the *question* is probably just to gauge how much cache the term retains in the former sense.

Comment: Aside: probably worth reminding anyone reading this that there's a good chance you are responsible for the ergonomics of your own job; unless/until you're injured, your employer probably isn't required to do anything to reduce the toll your work takes on your body. So... It's worth your time to investigate your options ahead of time: take some measurements, make adjustments to how your work area is arranged, and buy equipment that fits **your** body - *whether or not it has "ergo" on the label.* Beats spending months in pain recovering from an injury later.

Answer (score 28):

This survey takes a while and I want to save my progress to do later but it's not allowed

Comment: Thanks for your interest! You should be able to leave and come back to the survey as long as you use the same machine/browser; it should remember you based on a cookie (so long as you’re not using an incognito browser).

Comment: @JuliaSilge - thats not how it happened to me, I hit the back button on my PC to go back to previous question and it started all over again.

Answer (score 24):

One of these options is not like the others.

[image: bisexual || queer]

Why are Bisexual and Queer lumped together? I am not aware of any inherent relationship between the two. Honestly I'm not even sure what "Queer" is supposed to mean in this context. The other "or" options appear to be at least somewhat related. Should there be an option for "straight, heterosexual, or maybe Matt from accounting if I've had a couple beers"?

Comment: Wha'?! Yeah, this doesn't make any sense. I don't claim any particular expertise in gay stuff, but per my understanding (and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queer)), "queer" is basically a catchall meaning "non-straight" or "non-cis" or "non-gender-conforming". Lumping it with "bisexual" is bizarre, and probably means that lots of gay or asexual people who *also* identify as queer (due to it being a catch-all) will tick both boxes.

Comment: Additionally, due to it being a loaded/politicised term - from what I understand from occasionally wandering into Tumblr it was originally a slur like "faggot" and there are a lot of gays who still consider it offensive - it being lumped in there may *deter* people who actually identify as bisexual from ticking the box. It ought to be its own box, if it's going to be on there at all.

Comment: @MarkAmery that's exactly my point. I'm bisexual. I don't consider myself particularly queer. And yes, even if a Q has been added to LGBTQA++ (or whatever the acronym is now) depending on context Queer can definitely be used as a slur. I understand as programmers that `(bisexual || queer) == true` but that seems to be missing a certain _je ne sais quoi_ of the the matter.

Comment: FWIW, I answered in my own words, "Bisexual, not queer".

Comment: LGBTQA++ sounds like the gayest programming language ever.

Comment: It's _fabulous_ and it's got QA built right in. We can't go wrong. Until Microsoft comes out with LGBTQA#.

Comment: @MarkAmery More particularly, "queer" involves expression ("gay-acting" instead of "straight-acting but actually gay", etc), rather than sexual preference like all the others.

Comment: Also: why checkboxes? By definition if one *identifies* as X, then all other choices are off.

Comment: @Sklivvz Nope, for example you can be Asexual and Gay and something else in your own words. Or you could consider yourself to be Bisexual, Queer and Pansexual.

Comment: "Or you could consider yourself to be Bisexual, Queer and Pansexual." That has about as much informational value as saying that you identify as a "Ferrari vice-janitor in the Jedi Temple on Coruscant".

Comment: You can't be both straight and gay because by definition that's being bisexual and there's a choice for that. You can't be asexual (definition: "without sexual feelings or associations") and gay (definition: "sexually attracted to people of one's own sex"), one excludes the other. If your sexuality is fluid then there's the "in your own words" box.

Comment: Not that I even understand why this question is relevant on this survey, but given that it is included, (and given [the company's past action/stand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297871/)) it's disappointingly hilarious to have this little nugget of bi-erasure. And even leaving that aside, what if one's answer is "bi AND queer"?

Comment: @Sklivvz *"asexual and gay"* is coherent for definitions of those words commonly used in queer/leftist/intersectional-feminist  groups that distinguish being hetero- or homosexual from being hetero- or homoromantic, and treat the terms "straight' and "gay" as being nonspecific in whether they refer to sexuality or to relationship preference. In that vernacular, to say that I am "asexual and gay" would mean that I experience no sexual attraction or desire, but that with that caveat I nonetheless wish to be in something like a normal romantic relationship, and want that to be with another man.

Comment: @Cristina without going full "I identify as an attack helicopter", there are distinctions between -sexual and -romantic identities. You can be bisexual but heteroromantic. If you're not "straight" things get.....a little messy sometimes.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar If you're not straight, then you're "other" (at least as far as such a survey goes). In my opinion, the categories cannot be changed every day just because one person out of 7 billion has come up with a new identity and doesn't feel accurately represented. That's also the reason why such categories never make sense -- there will always be someone who doesn't fit any of the little specialised niches.

Comment: @Cristina _"If you're not straight, then you're 'other'"_ I hope that you can revisit this statement and understand how condescending it is.

Comment: @Cristina gee, thanks for that. I really needed to get knocked down a peg this morning. Guess I'll slink back to the closet now.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I apologise -- I didn't mean it in an offensive way. I just don't think labelling everyone with a growing numbers of labels is the way to go. I personally don't even understand why we need straight/gay/etc., hence my complaint about categories. I am perfectly fine to be "other", if "straight" is not available.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It was not meant in a condescending way. See my answer to mikeTheLiar -- I simply find such categories useless. If I personally don't find an option that suits me, I'll happily pick "other".

Comment: *"I just can't make sense of why these young'uns keep coming up with these new made-up categories when 'straight' and 'weird sexual deviant' are enough to adequately cover everyone!"*

Comment: @MarkAmery That's not at all what Cristina is saying and it's rude of you to suggest so by putting words in her mouth.

Comment: @TylerH As far as literal meaning goes, it seems to me that in fact it *is* what's she's saying - she's said, explicitly, that "straight" and "other' are sufficient categories for the survey and that she doesn't understand why people need to keep inventing such categories. I'm distorting the tone and the connotations for the sake of mischief, certainly - but I think taking someone's literal meaning and framing it differently is a legitimate rhetorical device for looking at their beliefs from a different perspective, rather than just a mean way of slandering them. Your view may differ.

Comment: @MarkAmery No, what she said was that *this survey* only considers people to be straight or some kind of 'other'. And then she goes on to claim a pretty progressive stance on the matter, which is one of entirely non-binary choices (e.g. no categories). For you to imply that she is old-fashioned, homophobic, etc. with your quip is wrong, disingenuous, and libelous (not slanderous).

Comment: @TylerH I've not said that she's old-fashioned, nor homophobic - nor do I presume that she's either of those things. But I thank you for pointing out that the connotations and implications of things that we say could be insulting to people, even in the absence of any explicit or intended insult - it turns out that we understand each other quite well after all!

Comment: @MarkAmery I've used the vocabulary definitions making my point. I understand that in some smaller circle things are different, but this is a worldwide, non anglosaxon specific survey and presumably people will use a dictionary to know the meaning of things. As such, and for the large majority of the survey takers (no matter their sexual orientation), such a choice of layout will seem incorrect, confusing and/or weird. It seems to me that we are privileging the point of view of the few here.

Comment: I agree that these options could be improved. If they are going to be non standard then Matt from accounting should *totally* be there. If not, then they should conform to the standard for these types of questions, already endlessly debated and available in the US census (https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/4063196-2020-CBAMS-Survey-Questionnaire-091517.html#document/p8/a378630#document/p8/a378630). The options are: 1) Gay or Lesbian, 2) Straight (that is, not gay or lesbian), 3) Bisexual, 4) Other, 5) I don't know the answer/Prefer not to answer

Answer (score 23):

## Rank: What do you find most important in an ad

(I'm not sure this was the exact wording, feel free to correct)

I don't get what I should be answering here. I have never:

- intentionally looked at an ad
- continued reading an ad as soon as I realized it was one
- intentionally clicked an ad
- gotten any value whatsoever out of an ad

And so I'm not sure what this question is supposed to mean at all. I guess it is better when it doesn't intentionally pretend to be an ad, but other than that?

Comment: They are interested in improving their advertising. Those who are find close to nothing important in an ad (like me) will have difficulties answering this question. It's probably badly posed.

Comment: The most important thing in an ad from my POV is that it can be easily ignored or blocked.

Answer (score 21):

Plan for five years' time doesn't include full-time parenthood, volunteer work, or founding of non-profit organisations as possible goals.

As I type this - on my open-source OS written by altruistic volunteers, on a site whose entire raison d'être is enabling programmers to share knowledge out of goodwill - I can't help but feel sad about the answers that are left out on this question, and the fact that nobody has yet pointed it out:

[image]

What if I want to found a non-profit, rather than a profit-making company? What if I want to have kids and become a stay-at-home dad, working on open source projects for the good of the world while my wife earns the money to support us? I can't express any of those aspirations here.

Comment: "Working as a founder or co-founder of my own company" doesn't specify the company is profit-making, so I don't really see the dilemma there.

Comment: @whrrgarbl I imagine the definitions here are complicated and differ by jurisdiction (and I'm not going to pretend to have much of a clue), but not all (or even most? I don't really know.) nonprofit organisations are companies.

Comment: There still needs to be an "Other" or "None of the above" choice.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Yes, I suppose that's true. There are certainly possible aspirations that probably *shouldn't* be explicitly on the list, like *"starting my own criminal enterprise stealing credit card numbers"*, and they need to be encompassed somehow. :)

Answer (score 19):

I guess I work for a very old-fashioned company.  Does anybody else work for a company that coordinates or shares information using telephone calls, or in-person conversations, or email, or is it all proprietary buzzwords that I've never heard of?

Comment: Yep, I used the fill-in-the-blank box for this one. "Email, phone, through the cubicle wall.."

Comment: I even dared to mention acoustic communication including near range direct visual contact.

Answer (score 18):

There are too many US-centric questions to feel comfortable. Where should I rank health insurance importance when it's 100% free and granted the moment you are born in 99% of the countries around me?

Same applies for parental leave, retirement funds, etc.: they're all enforced by law, and as far as I know, it's the same almost anywhere I might work.

The questions and results of this answer should be divided by continent and then by country, to not skew the data. Hope this can be fixed for the 2019 developer survey.

Answer (score 17):

I took the survey and here is what I think about it:

**jobs:**

I'm currently not looking for a job and, like last year, it annoyed me a lot (almost to the point of quitting all together) that the survey continued on about jobs and work experience even though I stated I don't have any (shouldn't be too hard I guess) however it made me sit through a ton of questions that I simply could not answer.

I've also stated in my survey that I'd like to personalize my experience on SO more. For example I'd love to be able to turn off SO Careers all together 
 as it does not interest me, leaving me not only happier when using this site but also allowing SO to show me more relevant ads instead.

**AI:**

Why? I mean why so specifically AI? Are you guys up to something?

**Personal Info:**

Again why? Since when does a programmer form need to know my sexual orientation? I've never seen an ad about a sexual related thing on this site (as I don't think it would generate much traffic here)

**Length:**

I said that the survey was appropriate in length and nor difficult nor easy to fill. but thinking about it I might come back on that decision and say it is a bit too long...

**Things that you could add next year:**

I think the survey is created to generate more profit for SO (as it's promoting SO Careers and harvesting info which can be use to improve ads for the user) and I'm totally OK with that! However I would have liked to see something in return like:

- Allow for more elaborating on answers. Questions about the way SO works could be answers with agree to disagree (and 3 options in between) but I was unable to explain myself (this even cause me to change from my answer as I was unable to justify my original choise)
- Allow for a better feature request section (it was a one line question with minimal space to answer)

Other that that I think it was a good survey

Answer (score 17):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) The followup question (missing from the survey for a short period due to a bug) now appears.

> What is your current gross salary (before taxes and deductions), in Euros (€)? Please enter a whole number in the box below, without any punctuation. If you are paid hourly, please estimate an equivalent weekly, monthly, or yearly salary.

So what am I supposed to enter here? Weekly, monthly or yearly salary, however I choose? If I type in 10000, how would you know this is my monthly or yearly earning? *Please*, have your survey tested extensively before making thousands of people answer it.

Also, what is the use of this question? I am working halftime right now. The yearly salary (which is what I entered) looks as if I were underpaid. For a meaningful comparison, this question should ask for the hourly wage.

Also also,

> Which of the following libraries, frameworks, and tools have you done extensive development work in over the past year, and which do you want to work in over the next year?

There are so many libraries out there, I could instantly name 10 which I have been using "extensively" and which havent been on this tiny list. Whats the point of this question?

Comment: Same here, I work only 10 hours a week (and of course earn much less than if it was 40 hours), but there is no way to specify it.

Comment: +1, *how would you know this is my monthly or yearly earning?*

Comment: Briefly, there was a bug where the follow-up question ("Is this salary weekly, monthly, or yearly"?) did not show up. We will see what we can do with the salary info for people who took the salary during this brief window, but we may have to replace these with blank values. As a data scientist, this HURTS as you can imagine.

Comment: Briefly? I just went through the survey today and it didn't appear, and in reading the posts here various that other s sat didn't appear for me.

Answer (score 15):

Just completed the survey, I have two suggestions

**About AI**

You asked me if I'm actually interested in AI (and I'm not) but previously I had to answer to 3 questions about it: wouldn't be more logical to ask first if the user is interested about this topic so, depending on the answer, he could skip all the related questions?

---

**Unethical code**

> Imagine that you were asked to write code for a purpose or product that you consider extremely unethical. Do you write the code anyway?

At a first reading this is how I placed the round brackets:

> Imagine that you were asked to write code *(for a purpose or product that you consider extremely unethical)*. Do you write the code anyway?

because several years ago at the beginning of my career I had to write code for a real unethical *product*: then, reading at the available answers I realized the real question (maybe?) was

> Imagine that you were asked to write code that you consider extremely unethical *for a purpose or product*. Do you write the code anyway?

I feel this question could be better rephrased.

---

P.s. : no jar with the candies this year? "*Mr. Anderson you disappoint me*"

[image]

Comment: You are making me confused now about the ethical question. Not sure how I should have answered it now. :)

Comment: the point is : this question is actually asking if you wrote unethical *code* (e.g. hundreds of popup, no support for assistive technology...) or if you wrote code for unethical *products*? there is a huge difference.

Comment: Welp, guess I misunderstood the ethics questions then.

Comment: Maybe I'm the only one but I found the ethics portion extremely vague to the point where I was constructing various scenarios to try to make sense of it.  e.g. could this be some sort of Edward Snowden situation, etc.

Comment: @RandyLevy Similar here, my issue with this whole section was that there's little leeway for situations involving coercion.  At least there was a text box to explain it later on, unlike several of the other sections.

Comment: In common usage, _that_ introduces a restrictive clause, which comes immediately after noun phrase it modifies.  Thus the first reading was correct.  It's the purpose or product that was unethical.  I'm surprised anybody found this ambiguous.

Comment: Probably something on the answers made me think to the other possible reading, maybe because, as an employed coder, I am in control of the code and I have responsibilities for it, not about who should be my customer or my project. This led me to misunderstand the question.

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) (Edit: This [seems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361588/take-the-2018-developer-survey/361595#comment545944_361589) to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign))

Guys give me a hint. Should I leave them blank or tick those boxes?

[image: Bug 1][image: Bug 2][image: Bug 3][image: Bug 4][image: Bug 5]

Plus another [bug](/questions/tagged/bug): Why am I given checkboxes instead a group of radio buttons for **some** of them? I suppose *all* of them should be radio buttons (from which you can select only one for each group).

Comment: A _None of the above_ would've been nice here

Comment: Tick the box, but then untick it and leave it blank for 6 minutes, then type "I prefer not to answer" in the "own words" option

Comment: Checkboxes are on purpose here because people may want to check off more than one. Having none of the above does make some sense, I agree... I thought the "if any" might cover that but perhaps not.

Comment: @KristinaLustig The problem is with the wording, leaving it blank makes it seem like you'd prefer not to answer, when you may be more than happy to.

Comment: This was already posted as the first answer to this question, why post it again? Certainly the repeated screenshots are not necessary either.

Comment: Please make pictures smaller (if not remove some)

Comment: So post a second answer then. Or just remove the first bug, since it's duplicated.

Comment: Besides, obviously you cannot belong to multiple age groups, or answer both "yes" and "no" as to whether you have children. Radio buttons = one choice, checkboxes = multiple choices.

Comment: @Stijn But you can be gay and straight but not bisexual according to this survey (I'm assuming it was done like that to avoid any offence)

Answer (score 14):

The "how many years" question has non-contiguous answers, meaning some people can't select a correct answer because they're in one of the gaps between answers:

[image]

I've been coding for 5 and a half years. What answer am I meant to pick?

Comment: Isn't that "3 years <= experience < 6 years"?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto maybe. Or maybe I should round to the nearest year. The survey doesn't say.

Comment: `int coding_years = 5 + 1/2;` If you have coded for 5 years, you must have learnt about integer arithmetic :P

Comment: Have you coded for 5 years? true. Have you coded for 6 years? false.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga by that logic, I could just as well pick the *0-2 years* option.

Comment: @mark why would you do that though?

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga I wouldn't, but the point is that it can't be the correct logic to apply to interpret the meaning of these answers, because it doesn't identify a unique answer.

Comment: Seems like this should be a slider, or freeform. Easier for entry, and then whoever analyzes it can use whatever bins they desire (including trying out different bins).

Comment: Proper list:
0-2.9999999999999999999999999999999
3-5.9999999999999999999999999999999
6-8.9999999999999999999999999999999

Comment: @GEOCHET So you speculate. But maybe it's 0-2.4999999999999999999999999999999, 2.5-5.4999999999999999999999999999999 5.5-8.4999999999999999999999999999999. The whole point is that we don't know, and that different answerers will have interpreted it differently.

Comment: I was disappointed it stopped at 30+.  We're not all millennials!

Answer (score 12):

The whole "benefits package" question makes no sense to me.

[image]

I'll concede that some of these things - like parental leave, company-provided transport, or company-cooked meals - are quality-of-life benefits that different people might trade off differently against money based upon how much they personally value them. But they're a minority. All of *these* things, on the other hand, are strictly financial benefits, directly fungible with money:

- Salary and/or bonuses
- Retirement or pension savings matching
- Fitness or wellness benefit
- Conference or education budget
- Childcare benefit
- Stock options or shares
- Health insurance

Thus, the obvious answer - and surely the only remotely rational one - is "I'll value them in proportion to the dollar value that they have to me, given my circumstances." But since the relative size of these things can vary wildly between employers, that means that ordering them basically consists of me guessing at what the dollar value of each benefit is at a typical employer and ordering by that, rather than the ordering in any way reflecting my values. I'm not sure that this process produces any useful data whatsoever.

If you want to elicit information about how much I value particular benefits, you'd be better off removing all the strictly financial benefits  and then asking how much salary-or-equivalent I'd be willing to sacrifice for each of a series of fluffier benefits like having the company cook my meals and having a big equipment allowance so I can buy some nice monitors for my desk. But what do you expect to learn from asking me what category I'd prefer the $$$ I get paid to fall under on my payslip?

Comment: Can't you just order the list the way **you** like it? Converting items into "amount of $$$" and ordering by that is very *programmish* way. They probably just want to know what is the most/least demanding benefits to you personally, maybe there will be some interesting finding for certain groups of persons (e.g. by sex, by family status, etc).

Comment: @Sinatr why would there be any correlation with any of those things? A $50k salary and a $1k food budget is the same amount of money as a $51k salary, whether you're a man or a woman. The only place there's going to be a correlation is where there's a financial benefit that is only available to particular groups - a public transport budget is useless to me if I can only get into work by car - but even then, the value of a $1k public transport budget to someone who commutes by train is $1k; how are they meant to order that against salary in any way besides "salary's bigger, so matters more"?

Comment: I answered this one as if I were comparing offers. "All else being equal, if Company A gives me $X for conferences, but Company B gives me $X fitness benefits, which would I prefer?" (Things I didn't care about went in to the bottom, e.g. childcare benefits since I don't have any dependents). Also in the US, healthcare can be difficult to assign a straight dollar value to - you might pay the same amount under two different plans but get very different coverage.

Comment: @MarkAmery Well, what I was looking for (flexible hours) isn't there, and is [preferred by women more than men](https://money.usnews.com/money/blogs/outside-voices-careers/2011/11/17/professional-women-choosing-flexibility-over-higher-pay) - so yes, there will be correlations outside of equivalent dollar amount, even when it's unrelated to group availability.

Comment: @Izkata sure, flexible hours is a great example of something that you might trade off against salary but which different people (or demographics) might put very different dollar values on. I can think of lots of others - like ability to work remotely, or opportunities to contribute to open source, or job title, or whether the job involves managing other people, or commute distance, or length of work hours. But my whole point is that (besides "parental leave") the options here aren't things like that - they're all just "$$$" or "$$$ with strings attached".

Comment: On this Q and on the adjacent drag-to-order Q there are a couple of items that are important and a couple that I really do not care about. For the remaining 5 or 6 the order is unimportant.

Comment: I disagree with the premise of the OP.  Most of those benefits are difficult-to-impossible to assign a monetary value to.  Stock, for example, involves a very different level of risk and potential reward and timing than salary.  Some people would gladly take a lower salary for more stock on the possibility that they could make a lot more money on the stock.  For others, the predictability of wages is more important.  Even a bonus typically only has a target, and thus has risk and reward factors that are not directly comparable to wages.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Yes, if I was interviewing at Google, I'd view stock options in a different light to interviewing at Yahoo. Also health insurance to somebody in the UK is different to health insurance to somebody in the US where it might be literally life or death.

Comment: Why did I not get shown this question...

Answer (score 10):

I wasn't sure how to answer the question regarding whether or not I contribute to Open Source.

I upload my personal projects to Gitlab under MIT/GPL/etc. licenses, but I don't contribute to third-party software. I don't know if that would count as "contributing", so I answered "no".

In the future, it might be better to distinguish between "I release my own code under a FLOSS licence" and "I contribute patches to projects with a FLOSS licence".

**EDIT:** Related: [Survey question "Do you contribute to open source projects" should not be a binary response](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361637/4200092)

Answer (score 10):

I am seeing an advert for the survey although I have already completed it. It's in German (which is probably correct, assuming I am in Germany), but when I took the survey initially, it was in English. There is no way to dismiss this advert, no voting or any other means to rate the ad like there is for external adverts.

[image: German survey ad]

In addition to that, I do not recall there being a question like the one in this ad in the survey.

> Mac or Windows? [Your choice]

This is very misleading. (I would chose neither, by the way).

Answer (score 9):

In previous surveys I was asked to optionally share my Stack Overflow user id. However, this time that was not requested.

An email was requested optionally at the end of the survey. Is this used as an attempt to tie into my Stack Overflow account? What if the email given was not associated with my account? Was my account automatically associated due to being currently logged in?

Comment: The request for your email was, as it said ("Please share the best email address at which to contact you for further research"), for research purposes. We occasionally like to speak directly with developers to learn more about developer opinions, and that's what we use the research list for. At the end of the survey, you were automatically linked back to SO and if you were logged in, you were assigned the silver badge. If you were not logged in, you would be prompted to log in.

Comment: That part was rather straightforward, however I was mostly curious about whether or not the data was associated with my Stack Overflow account directly, as I was under the impression that in past years if I had opted in to include my user id it was. Not that I mind either way, I was just curious if that was still the situation.

Comment: Ah, no, the survey data is not associated in our databases together with your account. The two data sources are separate and are not used together.

Comment: Data is not associated with your account ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361596/change-the-description-of-the-census-badge/361652#361652))

Answer (score 8):

Some technical issues (based on the Holy Handgranade of methodology in German Schnell, Rainer ; Hill, Paul B ; Esser, Elke: Methoden der empirischen Sozialforschung. München: Oldenbourg Wissenschaftsverlag, 2011 which isn't necessary for the marketing survery, but it's hard to do things badly on purpose if you have an idea how to do them right):

- All questions should have the possibility to answer "I don't know" and "I don't won't to answer" (there's a difference between both, so you need both of them). The fact that you can click next without selecting is not intuitive.
- The education of parents needs to be recorded separately for mother and father (including the options mentioned above).
- Multi-select checkboxes with one option "None of the above" don't make sense because "None of the above" and [one of the above] is never true.
- People contributing to the survey should be given the possibility to critique the survey at the end. It's considered polite.

Well trained sociology students probably know that and you should contact some of them before starting another survey. They can consult you in questions of dramaturgy and the right item scales (I'm not a professional, but I couldn't recognize any potential use for the generated data).

Comment: I'll give special emphasis on the separation of the mother and father education. Not only that, it's extremely hard for a non-US person to select options that make sense in the US. I won't translate every single option to then have to check what's the equivalent in my country

Answer (score 7):

The survey is missing "Prev" (or "Back" buttons) on the following questions:

- "In which country do you currently reside?"
- The page about college majors, industry / organization size, how long have you been coding
- "This section will focus on Stack Overflow usage and community questions"
- "If you could change anything about Stack Overflow, what would it be?"

Also, you can't clear the answer for "What is the highest level of education received by either of your parents? If you prefer not to answer, you may leave this question blank." It should have an option for "I prefer not to answer" like the other radio button questions on that page.

Comment: and in one of these questions - I hit the back button and bam all my half an hour's worth of effort disappeared.  The worst ever user experience design. Many of the questions had missing checkboxes.

Answer (score 6):

This was mentioned briefly in [another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361631), but I want to call it out explicitly as well. I have no idea how to answer "Think back to the last time you updated your resumé, CV, or an online profile on a job site. What is the main reason that you did so?"

> [image]

None of those options apply at all, as I generally update my CV when something happens that's worth adding to it... which is what happened last time. I don't know if it's really feasible to enumerate every possible scenario here, but a "none of the above" option or, as suggested in the comments, "I regularly make changes to my resume to keep it up to date" would be great next year.

Comment: I agree, though I do think "I regularly make changes to my resume to keep it up to date" should also be an option.

Comment: @BSMP Yeah, for sure. I added that to my answer.

Comment: Huh? What's wrong with "My job status or other personal status changed" then? I don't see the problem, TBH.

Comment: @MrLister "I built something cool" isn't what comes to mind when I think of a "job status change".

Answer (score 5):

## Questions I found difficult to answer

### In a typical week, how many times do you exercise?

How do you define one unit of exercise? Walking up the stairs? Walking my kids to nursery? Scooting to work? Or does only a gym session count?

### How satisfied are you with your current job?

There are many different aspects to jobs and I personally find it very difficult to sum up the different conflicting feelings I have.

### Which of the following best describes what you hope to be doing in five years?

I wasn't sure how realistic I was supposed to be here, the range from most likely to fantasy is quite broad.

Comment: Questions in a survey need a certain level of simplification, especially with the total amount of time spent on the survey or social desirability bias in mind. Given the mistakes that SO made and that could be avoided/fixed by a few sociology students in 4th semester given 50$ each, I can't estimate if it's on purpose or not, but it makes other aspects more difficult otherwise.

Comment: I think you're overthinking it. Would you tell someone "yep, I exercised today" if you walked up a flight of stairs? If a casual acquaintance said "Do you like your job?" would you answer yes/no/kinda? And they asked "*hope* to be doing", not "what do you *actually see* yourself doing".

Answer (score 5):

Please add the ability to resume the survey later.Because it lasts too long and I had to close it after 10 minutes in the first try, when I want to enter again Survey began start from 0.

> An example: I start to survey, after 15 min i need to go, and close survey page(computer turned off
>   ). Then i want to continue the survey its not possible.

Answer (score 4):

So many ads questions (I don't really mind, though), I felt one was missing:

> Do you use your Reduce Ads privilege?

I'd find it interesting because I don't use it and have Adblock and Adblock Plus disabled explicitly for the Stack Exchange network (some ads have actually been useful)

Comment: I guess they can see that information from the database though

Comment: @AshleyMedway How often I'm active and the amount of activity also, and it's still asked...

Comment: I see your point, maybe there's some value in how active you are VS how active you believe you are?

Comment: Wait, you can toggle that?

Comment: @BlackVegetable Yes, in your preferences

Comment: @AshleyMedway Except for the claim (both in the survey, comments on this question, and in other questions) that the survey is not linked to your SO account.  So they couldn't correlate the other ad questions with the setting.

Answer (score 3):

I started answering the questions until the section speaking about Advertising. This section is expensive and asks a lot of questions. I dropped all out and close the survey whiteout submitting anything.
If you want to do -like others do- a commercial/financial survey for SO, you can do it separately and keep this one technically as possible.

Comment: As linked elsewhere (but not visibly enough!) this survey has always been about advertising on SO to begin with: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/12/21/stack-overflow-annual-survey/

Comment: And why you ask technical questions so?  it is a bait?

Comment: You have a huge outreach to people willing to answer questions and interested in results. Why just make it an advertisement thing if you can get other answers too?

Comment: _"whiteout submitting anything"_: Don't be so sure about that. All your answers _are_ registered ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus I thought responses are local and there are some Submit Button at the end (which I not reached). Anyway Adblock do job ;)

Comment: Adblock doesn’t block any of that.

Comment: @Cerbrus you must read between lines...

Answer (score 3):

On the question "Which development environment(s) do you use regularly?" the option "Xcode" has an incorrectly capitalised 'C'.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't write down all exact wordings as I was afraid of hitting back (and revisiting the questionnaire might skew the results even more, but there are many answers in this thread already discussing skewed results), but here are some of my thoughts about some questions and how to maybe improve them.

---

The question "I am not as good at programming as my peers" is no rating but a yes/no question, which doesn't even provide any meaningful insights because it eventually boils down to an almost forced-choice into "fully agree".

Either you are at the same level as your peers, at which point you have to strongly disagree with the sentence, or you are not, then you have to fully agree with the sentence.

If you are at the exact same level as your peers, then this question is fine. If there is at least one peer who is better or worse than you, you have to fully agree with this sentence. Since it is highly unlikely that all of your peers are at the exact same level as you, the only rational choice left to answer is "fully agree".

On the other hand, if we try to argue what "being good at programming" means, this question gets even worse. Does being good mean being able to write software faster? More reliable? Better tested? More readable code? With more detailed documentation? To the point? Or is it more about the ability of abstract thinking? Solving problems? Is a peer better in programming than me (or worse than me) if I can only write my little Python data analysis script while she writes enterprise Java software, while neither of us could do the other person's job, because she knows how to do OOP and GUI and whatever programming in Java but has no clue about how to vectorize a call for numpy?

To improve this question it should be outlined what "being as good as" means exactly about the relation between me and my peers. Additionally the negation should be removed, it is much more difficult to understand and I almost accidentaly clicked "fully disagree" despite my thourogh analysis of the question. Also the question could be more meaningful if asked whether a persons sees him- or herself as being "better" (whatever this means) than peers, or worse. This could even be split in two. But I dislike those rating scales anyway, as they are almost always ill-defined.

---

The list of programming, markup, and scripting languages is arbitrary. There was e.g. HTML in there, but Markdown, which every stackoverflow contributor uses every now and then, was not listed. Or RST. Or something like yaml. In academia, LaTeX is quite common. "Extensive development" (or coding or something like that was mentioned) might or might not mean that it actually should perform some computations or whatsoever – but then, why mention markup languages in the first place?

I missed a lot of frameworks, tools, etc. which are used in academia (and also outside). Sure, there was a mention of Matlab – but there's also Octave. Tensorflow and PyTorch were mentioned – what about keras and caffe? What about OpenCV and dlib? Even for more industry-related tools there are flaws: We got React, but what about vuejs? Or simpler, what about things like bootstrap? There are many other answers in this thread arguing about that, so I won't continue more here.

I feel like the best way to go would have been to either provide far more exhaustive lists or to provide no lists at all and just give users an option to write down as many programming languages, scripting languages, markup languages, frameworks, tools, database systems, etc. as they liked.

---

My "workstation" is a difficult concept. I do have a desktop at home at which I sometimes work to test things on Windows. It also dual boots to linux. It has two monitors. But I also have a place in the university office where I can either use the linux machine there (using two monitors) or even hook up the two monitors to my Macbook (effectively ending up with three monitors). Then again, after lunch I often stay in the cafeteria, have a chat and then work there, effectively putting my "workstation" into a one-monitor-macbook. So "it varies from 1 to 3 monitors, depending on the circumstances" is a much better description of my workstation setup. And I guess it's similar to other people as well, as they will have company laptop they can take around and sit in some cozy corners, or at their desks with multiple monitors, or at a coffee shop, etc. – at least that's what I did in the past.

So the questionnaire should treat modern flexible work environments a little bit better, work from home, in the office, with a fixed desk, etc. etc.

---

The  notion of "work" vs. "being a student" is a big issue throughout the questionnaire. Lots of "work" questions apply to being a student, but for example many students do not have a salary (I said my salary is 0 monthly, but technically all three answers would have applied).

It might make sense to distinguish more between different types of work, e.g. paid/unpaid or hobby/student/academics/business, ...

Comment: You know, instead of the questionnaire being wrong, maybe you're not exactly the target audience? They can't cover all possible cases...

Comment: Indeed, that is not impossible, but mind: "The Stack Overflow Developer Survey is for those who write code as a hobbyist, student, or professional.", as is written if you answer the initial questions with "None of these" and two "No"s. I also don't argue that the questionnaire is wrong in general (although the "I am not as good at programming as my peers" question reads weird), but pointed out some possible improvements to really cover students.
But if the questionnaire is only posed for people who are working with industry frameworks on a paycheck in the US, then I'm not the target audience.

Comment: I will remove the section about the first question though, as I tried again how it really works and even with "None of these" I would have been able to participate (because the other two options apply).

Comment: I read the "I am not as good at programming as my peers" question as one about confidence and not objective ability. Even if it's really about ability you can still use the range to set your ability, ie, strongly disagree = I am better than my peers, disagree = I am as good as my peers, etc.

Comment: The problem is not the objective ability or subjective confidence, but the ambiguity. I could also say "strongly disagree" for "worse than my peers", because "as good as" is agreeable, if and only if you are exactly as good as, otherwise you have to disagree. No matter into which direction you deviate. And of course, with the negation this changes and becomes more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous or not, don't ask for my sexual orientation. I know it was made very clear I didn't have to answer, but it still rubs me the wrong way to be asked.

---

I find the question extremely personal, more than anything else. Personal questions such as age, wage or having children are relevant; however, I feel that asking my sexual orientation is akin to asking whether I'm a virgin or not, or what my fetishes are. It's truly personal, and rude to even ask (regardless of whether I can give no answer).

As Vincent has pointed out in the comments, perhaps it's simply to gauge how welcoming SO is, but it's [also made clear that the survey is about marketing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361588/take-the-2018-developer-survey/361657?noredirect=1#comment546022_361588).

Comment: Why? You could just skip the question silently, instead you announce it in public and without any valid arguments (it rubs you?). I personally very curious in the number of females programmers, working with one is an experience I didn't have yet, must be a reason, maybe I should switch from C# to java or who knows...

Comment: I'm not talking about _gender_, I'm talking about sexual orientation. I don't mind the question about gender, because I can envision some stats on that. What are they hoping to see with sexual orientation? 3% of Ruby programmers are gay? 10% of C++ programmers are queer? Why is that useful? Note the OP says _"If you have any questions or feedback in general, we'd love to hear it, just post an answer or comment"_ which I've done. I felt it was valid feedback, but if not it can be deleted as _not an answer_.

Comment: @Tas It can be a way to investigate how welcome non-straight people feel in the SO community. If very few people were to check one of the corresponding boxes, it would be a clue that the situation is unsatisfying (though other reasons may have one not doing so).

Comment: @Tas I am French, and such questions are forbidden in France. I too used to be appaled when confronted with them. But not asking them often results in the denying of issues and the impossibility to factually document discriminations. I don't know what SO will actually do with this information, but it might be why they asked. Of course, it was absolutely legitimate of you not willing to answer.

Comment: @Tas Soon c++ programmers will start receiving more ads towards queers

Answer (score 0):

After selecting £ as my currency, when I submitted X,000 as my salary I was told that I couldn't have "more than two decimals". I didn't save the exact error, but it struck me as weird.

Comment: Sometimes the thousand separator is a , and other times a . Same goes for decimals. Maybe the system was taking your thousand separator to be a decimal point?

Comment: Yes, same issue with euros. I was amused that some people would put decimals when giving their salaries more than anything :D

Comment: I got the same error when selecting dollars. I'm not aware of any locale which uses dollars as their primary currency and , as the decimal separator.

Comment: It clearly states 'without any punctuation', just type an integer.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid But the decimal point/comma isn't _punctuation_, it's part of the number. And if "_without any punctuation_" does mean you cannot have _any_ non-digit characters, then how do you enter the two decimals that _are_ (apparently) allowed?

Comment: @TripeHound, [punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation) = *inserting points or other small marks into texts, in order to aid interpretation*. If you are asked to "enter number without punctuation", that clearly means just one thing: only digits are allowed.

Comment: @Sinatr The thousands separator clearly counts as punctuation: `1,000,000` or `1.000.000` is clearly easier to interpret than `1000000`. However, I'd contend that the decimal separator is more than just an _aid_ to interpretation, it is a integral part of non-integer numbers. The fact that there's a limit of two decimals implies you _are_ allowed to use such numbers (if you're _not_ allowed to specify decimal places, the error message is wrong and the original label should have been "_In **whole numbers** without punctuation._").

Comment: @TripeHound, *"is clearly easier to interpret"* - yes, for a human. Survey data will be collected and presented in human-readable way don't have doubts. What they try to avoid (as it seems to me) is to implement parsing for this field. For me it's totally ok to ask *another programmer* for thing like this: "Hey, do me a favor, I don't want to spend my time on this, can you enter salary as a number please". Selling such survey to a normal user (non-programmer) would not be acceptable and I am a bit surprised you are trying to act as one.

Comment: @Sinatr Believe me, I'm acting as a "pedantic programmer", not a "normal user" :-). You asserted that _punctuation_ = _marks ... to aid interpretation_ and I agree that a thousands separator is such a mark (whether used on input or output). The decimal separator is not an _aid_ to interpretation, but an _integral part_ of it (`1.00` or `1,00` is _different_ to `100`, not just _easier to interpret_). [_**cont**_]

Comment: [...] The problem with the survey is that while it (not unreasonably) seeks to ban punctuation (=000s separator), it _apparently_ accepts values to two decimal places (given the original error message). One reason to bar the 000s separator is the comma/point problem, but by accepting decimal places, it persists (in the OP's case, _either_ their locale indicates the decimal separator is a comma, or the parsing code assumes it might be). The sensible thing is to only accept whole numbers (without punctuation _or_ decimal separator), but the original error message suggests they're not doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I am all set to start my journey with [2018 Developer Survey](https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_bedBQlMexcTr5WJ?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=meta&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2018-collection&award=a44ddbce912140a4b13ebc0bdcfd7a64&site=stackoverflow.com) now. But I wonder why no heading on the survey preface page?

[image: 2018 Developer Survey]

Answer (score -5):

I did not get to do the survey. I am doing coding to find a job, therefore I did not click that I am a professional. Since I want to earn money from it I did not choose hobby too. The survey closed for me after this stating I should either code as a hobby or as a proffesional. Not able to reopen and edit.

Comment: I think if you are coding or studying with the intention of making it your career, it would be considered _professional_. If you have another career, or just don't intend to make programming a career, it would be considered a hobby (likely even if you make money off it)

Comment: Well I cannot undo it now. I think I am leaving it at that. I also find it difficult not to connect money with being a professional. Thanks anyway for your two cents.

Answer (score -5):

Can we have more questions on diversity in teams?

Answer (score -19):

Why are there so many questions about ads? I had to quit the survey.

Comment: You didn't have to do anything. You chose to.