# Think back to the last time you updated your resumé

Tags: discussion, survey-2018

There is a question in the 2018 survey:

> Think back to the last time you updated your resumé, CV, or an online profile on a job site. What is the main reason that you did so?

Personally, I tend to just update it ad-hoc: when I've done something new; completed a project; etc.

The possible items only allow for options where something bad has happened or you've been told about a new job.

Can an "Other:" (free text input) be added or is this kind of thing locked down?

Comment: This one threw me off too. I left it blank, but I really wanted to answer "because I just like keeping it up to date." Now I'm curious how many people only update their CV when they're planning on using it [because something bad happened I guess].

Comment: `load resume, 8` ... `open 4,4` ... `cmd 4` ... `list` ... I feel offended that they totally missed the demographic that compulsively prints their resumes. I mean it's not like I've had this problem since the mid-80s or anything.

Comment: Why is the option about a personal change in status or whatever not relevant? I review my resume about every 12 months, unless something changes (I want to mention a specific project, gain expertise in a new tool or technology, get a new certification, etc). I forget the wording, but there was an option that seemed like it fit with that mindset.

Comment: @ThomasOwens It's not relevant because it puts too much burden on the respondent to guess at what the survey maker intended by the question.

Comment: last time I updated my resume, was because I learn a new technology or got a new skill and wanted to mention it in my resume. All for good reasons.

Comment: Upvoted because it's a good idea for *next* year, but not that I want it changed now.

Comment: I left an answer on the post mentioning this as well. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361631/552420

Comment: Yeah I had to pick an option which was not truthful but was "close enough". My reason: no CV was needed at all as they are becoming a thing of the past, but I did it anyway to make HR happy.

Comment: I wanted to answer "because I did something interesting and wanted to add it". For example, a new publication, or an additional responsibility at $JOB, or whatever. No such option existed and I was surprised it wasn't there. It only seemed that there were "negative" reasons to update ones resume offered as options.

Comment: Last time I updated my resumé was because I was trying to find my first “real” job. That isn’t an option in the survey. But then I realized that the survey technically said “or an online profile on a job site” and, for that, it was that I was on linkedin or SO Jobs for some reason and saw incorrect information which I wanted to correct. All the reasons listed on the survey seem weird to me, as if you’re only supposed to take the survey if you’ve tried to use your resumé to get a raise (is that actually a thing????)

Comment: Like other commenters, I'll sometimes update a (private) copy of my resume when I do something different at work, so more of a positive reason than the answers seem to suggest... I also chose the "My job status or other personal status changed" answer.