# Should I take the 2018 Developers' Survey if I no longer work as a developer?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2018

Should I take the 2018 Developers' Survey if I no longer work as a developer? I do have development experience, and could theoretically do the job again if someone was willing to hire me to do it, but I have more or less successfully transitioned to another career and have no current plans to return.

Comment: Sure, if you still participate (passively or actively) in any way with stackoverflow.com, or related programming Stack Exchange sites, your feedback and input will still be considered valuable.

Comment: [It's all about the ads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361588/take-the-2018-developer-survey?cb=1#comment546022_361588) so everyone's input is welcome.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes! In fact, we have a question that specifically asks about that.

> Which of the following options best describes you today? Here, by "developer" we mean "someone who writes code."

- I am a developer by profession
- I am not primarily a developer, but I write code sometimes as part of my work
- **I used to be a developer by profession, but no longer am**
- I am a student who is learning to code
- None of these

As you work through the survey, some of the questions may not apply to you as much, but you can either skip them or give your best answers today.

Comment: needs free-hand circle on the correct option

Comment: But it's not an image! Is there some magic by which I can free hand circle on Markdown? 

Comment: I'd be surprised if there were a specific free-hand circle option in Markdown. However, most OS's support screenshots ;)

Comment: Writing in Word, taking screenshot and posting it on SO. This is how we roll :-)