# Survey question "Do you contribute to open source projects" should not be a binary response

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2018

Early in the 2018 survey there was a question like "Do you contribute to open source projects" with a yes/no option. In the future, this should have more than two options. I wasn't sure what to put. Ultimately I decided to select "yes" on the response, but it's a very weak "yes".

Does submitting feature requests and bug reports to open source projects count as contributing? I have done that a few times in the past year. I have opened one pull request for an open source project, but it was just a change to misleading verbiage in their ReadMe.md file.

Also, it wasn't clear if the question was intended to just mean in the last year, or ever. I have created a few pull requests with actual code contributions to projects a few years ago, but nothing lately.

Comment: Yes, submitting bug reports and feature requests counts as contributing, as far as I am concerned. Most projects really do appreciate such contributions.

Comment: As a fellow sufferer from impostor syndrome, it would be nice to see a minor/major contributor in future surveys. While I agree my contribution was just that, it's of a different magnitude than those who put substantially more effort and time into it: The graveyard of a repo my previous employer had me put up because "OSS is a thing" means I've technically contributed hundreds of lines of code to OSS, but I don't consider myself a major contributor, given afaik it's been used by precisely zero people (we didn't even use it *shrug*).

Comment: I also had this decision, as I fixed some docs links for @Natty

Comment: I was also unsure about this. But ultimatley, bug reports should count as contribution, since you took time to ensure the bug is resproducible and formulate an adequate response for the devs.

Comment: What aoout just contributing code on `StackOverflow` (answering, commenting, ...) ? Doesn't this count as helping to an `open source project`?

Comment: I could have used a bit more explanation in this one.  If it was there, I missed it, but a simple underline on the word contribute and a pop-up list of examples of contributing would have made this question faster for me, as I was a bit confused.  I also would have liked a time period like other questions had.

Answer (score 37):

I am the maintainer of an open source project that is used moderately widely and in my opinion, submitting bug reports and feature requests absolutely counts as open source contribution. Your "yes" is absolutely valid, if you ask me!

Comment: Oh... I should have answered with yes then

Comment: If we're going too far, incrementing a   or ❤️  on a [pull-request](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/pull/155) will soon count as active contribution.

Answer (score 9):

It would probably be worth having several checkboxes, something like:

> What kind of contributions to Open Source projects did you make over
>   the last year?
>
> - I published code or patches
> - I participated to bug reports or feature requests
> - I improved the documentation
> - I participated in the setup of tools for collaborative development on an Open Source project
> - I published a set of open data
> - I participated in collaborative knowledge sharing like Wikipedia or StackOverflow
> - other: [free text]
> - none of the above

It might also be worth indicating whether this was done professionally or over free time (so 2 columns of checkboxes).

Comment: Don't forget about the time aspect though, a binary question will *normally*
 (not in the case where you aren't sure) be quicker to answer.

Comment: @DavidMulder Indeed. This would be for next year anyway, so the results of this year's yes/no question will probably help to refine it for next year.

Comment: "I participated in collaborative knowledge sharing like Wikipedia or StackOverflow"  That hardly counts as an open source project. And besides, it is mildly interesting to know if users of SO use SO...

Comment: Maybe the question should specify open source software since people now use the term "open source" to describe lots of things.

Comment: It's indeed hard to put a limit there, but for me this is definitively part of the open source community. I mentioned Stack Overflow a bit out of a joke, but maybe it should be explicitly excluded instead.