# 2018 Developer Survey - Missing Country/Territory

Tags: feature-request, survey-2018

The 2nd page of 2018 Stack Overflow Developer Survey asks:

> In which country do you currently reside?

I cannot seem to find **Taiwan** in the list.
It is also not listed under any other "common" names, such as **Republic of China (R.O.C.)**, or the erroneous **Taiwan, Province of China** or even **Chinese Taipei**.

I know Taiwan is kind of.. complicated. But the list seems to be faulty, I also noticed that Hong Kong (S.A.R.) is there but not Macau (S.A.R.).

What standard is used this year? Is it possible to update the list?

Comment: Also here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361638/1402846

Comment: lol, 'Taiwan is kind of.. complicated'.  Nobody wants to offend anyone else, so your country just sorta 'disappears' :)

Comment: Anyone out there in Hong Kong?  If so, could you look across the bay and check if Macau is still there?   :)

Comment: Slightly related, this is the first time I’ve seen “United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland” in a long time, typically “United Kingdom” would suffice.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We started the survey by using the default list of countries from our survey tool (Qualtrics) but we have since added Taiwan  and also an option "Other Country (Not Listed Above)" for very small countries. We apologize that we missed this important element from the start.