# Question on 2018 dev survey about "children or other dependents that you care for" is awkward

Tags: bug, survey-2018

This obviously isn't a question.  In the developer survey, there was no obvious way to provide comments about the survey itself.

One of the questions asked:

> Do you have any children or other dependents that you care for?

This is an odd question.  Yes, I have children.  Do I "care for them"?  Considering they moved out of the house years ago, I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: If your children have moved out of the house, and you are not financially supporting them, then they are not dependants of yours.  A dependant of yours is someone who is relying on you for basic necessities (housing, food, etc.).  Most people that are dependants are children who are dependents of their parents while they're still living with them, which is why the question mentions it specifically, but another example would be an elderly parent that you are taking care of.

Comment: The correct spot for such posts/remarks is even featured here on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361588/take-the-2018-developer-survey?cb=1

Comment: Note that this is an "or" question. It can be that you have neither child nor someone you take care for (is dependant of yours). If any of those are true (have childs or have a dependant) then the answer is yes.

Comment: @Braiam As stated, the question is ambiguously phrased, but the intent seems pretty clearly to be, "Do you have any children, or other dependents, that you care for?" rather than "Do you have any children, or other dependents that you care for?" (note the different comma placement).  It would be weird to ask if someone has any dependants or a non-dependant child, and entirely reasonable to indicate that children are most likely to be a dependant, given that many people don't know what a "dependant" is.

Answer (score 7):

The mention of "dependents" strongly suggests that "care for" refers to caregiving in this case. Using the phrase "care for" in this manner is not unheard of.

Having said that, not sure if this is any better:

> Do you have any children or other dependents that you are a caregiver to?

Or this:

> Are you an active caregiver to any children or other dependents?

This sounds much more natural:

> Do you have any children or other dependents that you look after?