# Filling out the survey is hard, let's go shopping

Tags: discussion, survey-2018

I started on the developer survey. Then I reached 'drag these items up and down the screen to get them in the right order.'

That was it for me -- more time and effort than I'm going to do to help you run your business. I'm grumpy, but I doubt that I'm unique in finding this to be too much toil.

This biases your selection towards people who like arranging things in order, or have a lot of time on their hands, or both.

Comment: In several of those list questions only 1 or two of the items were important. the rest were irrelevant, thus resulting in me giving an answer that wasn't at all accurate, because it suggested that several items were important or more important than some others, when in fact they weren't. I don't think the data from those questions outside of the first 2-3 choices will be all that useful anyway.

Comment: I started completing the survey and lost interest and abandoned it halfway through. I wonder what the stats are on people bailing mid way through.

Comment: Duplicate of one of the 'answers' under https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361588/take-the-2018-developer-survey. [Specifically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361614/512728)

Comment: To be fair, you probably spent more time complaining about the dragging questions than it would have taken to just drag the items around, but to each their own. Also, this does not appear to invite discussion; looks like more of a rant than anything else.

Answer (score -2):

## Find one or two important things, move them to the top, next question

I don't know how dragging a handful of list items around (you can enter a numerical value too!) is "too much effort." I wouldn't worry too much about getting the order *exactly perfect*, all you need to do is convey an approximation, and doing that takes ten to twenty seconds. Or about 1/60th the time it takes to do the whole survey.

Comment: It asked me to order the entire list, not to 'drag a couple.'

Comment: @bmargulies The list is already *in* an order. Drag one or two items to the top. Now you're done.

Comment: "done" for some value of "done". If that was what the survey designers wanted (pick 1 or 2 and leave the rest in haphazard order) that should be stated explicitly.

Comment: This is what I did as well: once through the list, moving things up to the top as I went. Stuff at the bottom that I couldn't quickly decide on, I didn't touch. I suppose that means their data won't be as accurate as it could be, but... _shrug_ that's their lookout.