# When is the 2018 Developer Survey closing?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2018

When is the 2018 Developer Survey closing ?

As mentioned in post [Take the 2018 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361588/take-the-2018-developer-survey) the survey was tentatively closing on January 26th [Timezone: Unknown, Year: Unknown]

[The World Clock — Worldwide](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/) does suggests January 26th, 2018 is history now.

Comment: If the day has already ended everywhere, it's possibly "some time after January 26 when the weekend's over and someone gets around to closing it"?

Comment: note the survey is still open and I just took it. I'm hoping my responses will be included. It also said I would get  the badge.

Comment: You'll get the timestamps of the last people completing the survey on https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census. Some people like me did it on January 29th.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It was 9:55am when you posted this question; that means it's still 9:55pm on January 26th in the [UTC-12:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9212:00) timezone. It's likely that Stack Overflow used the [Anywhere on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anywhere_on_Earth) convention here (or else somebody forgot to pull the plug on the survey).

Comment: i'm hoping they kept it open a little longer for late comers like me who really wanted to do it.

Comment: And what about the results? How long It will take to prepare them?

Comment: @AliMamedov SO wise it usually takes 6 to 8 da^H^H, wee^H^H^H, mont^H^H^H^H, [something](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) to happen.

Comment: @kayess I wonder how many people actually understand what ^H actually means, or even how many people actually had to use it!

Comment: @DavidG If they don't, they shouldn't be on SO ^D

Comment: @DavidG according to the commment ticker there are least five of you guys out there :)

Answer (score 7):

It is closed now. Trying to access it shows a message saying it has expired:

[image]

(reproduced logged in and out of SO/SE)

Comment: Jon is a cheater: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census